# Matching a web address through regex

Tags: c#, regex, url

I want to match a web address through regex which should capture http://www.google.com as well as www.google.com i.e. with and without protocol.

Comment: Did you mean to match specific domain names (e.g. google), or do you need to match arbitrary domain names?

Comment: i want to catch domain names with and without protocols

Comment: I found this answer very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4820675/1740705

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's going to depend on exactly what you want to capture ("FTP"? "/index.htm"?) because a general URI capture based on the RFC standard is very hard, but you could start with:

```
/^((https?\:\/\/)?([\w\d\-]+\.){2,}([\w\d]{2,})((\/[\w\d\-\.]+)*(\/[\w\d\-]+\.[\w\d]{3,4}(\?.*)?)?)?)$/
```

Complicated see?

Answer (score 2):

Try [RegexLib](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2).

Comment: Exactly the reply (and the link) I would have provided!

Answer (score 1):

Read [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). It is not just as easy as you might think it is. The job is easier if you only have a small set of URLs to parse.

Comment: You can get 'good enough' though, so this answer isn't particularly helpful

Comment: Its about as good an answer as there was one without full problem specification. To the extent of being a competitor for the top answer. The problem is few people read the RFCs and I having read one and written a IPV6 parser know how hard the job is.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
/google\.com/
```

?

It catches *http://www.google.com* , *www.google.com* , and even *google.com* for free! :-)

Comment: It also catches "Well I guess I could try searching for this regex on google.com, nah SO is better than google these days. Hmm, I wonder what's for lunch. Mmmm. Bacon"

Comment: Which, if you enter it in most browsers will bring you to google :)

Comment: SO is meant to be a reference so that when you search google, you end up here instead of another crappy site. So this question is fine.

Comment: @John: Please stop making paranoic comments and donevotes. This was a legitimate answer, advising how to match specific domain names (e.g. google.com).