# How to get domain name from URL

Tags: regex, url

How can I fetch a domain name from a URL String?

#### Examples:

```
+----------------------+------------+
| input                | output     |
+----------------------+------------+
| www.google.com       | google     |
| www.mail.yahoo.com   | mail.yahoo |
| www.mail.yahoo.co.in | mail.yahoo |
| www.abc.au.uk        | abc        |
+----------------------+------------+
```

Related:

- [Matching a web address through regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568864/maching-a-web-address-through-regex)

Comment: what about www.abc.def.ghi.au.uk?

Comment: What about “foo.bar.com”? And “foo.com”?

Comment: Well, the second post in minutes about a very similar topic -- homework?
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568864/maching-a-web-address-through-regex)

Comment: What for may I ask? It's hard to invent what for do you need domain names without 2nd level domain suffix (like .co.uk)

Comment: @ Hemal: in this case expected output is abc.def.ghi
@ Bombe: i need to remove www prefix anyways

Comment: Problem is not solvable. You can't tell if xx in foo.xx.yy has to be removed too (Why did you remove au.uk and not just uk?)

Comment: Agree with 'not solvable'. Too many mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: @Chinmay: Your terminology is all sorts of wrong here. All of the inputs you list are domain names, not URLs. This is a URL: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL`, the domain name in that URL is `en.wikipedia.org`

Comment: I found this answer very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4820675/1740705.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I once had to write such a regex for a company I worked for. The solution was this:

- Get a list of every [ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTLD) and [gTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) available. Your first stop should be [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/). The list from Mozilla looks great at first sight, but lacks ac.uk for example so for this it is not really usable.
- Join the list like the example below. **A warning:** Ordering is important! If *org.uk* would appear after *uk* then **example.org.uk** would match **org** instead of **example**.

Example regex:

```
.*([^\.]+)(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk|__and so on__)$
```

This worked really well and also matched weird, unofficial top-levels like *de.com* and friends.

The upside:

- Very fast if regex is optimally ordered

The downside of this solution is of course:

- Handwritten regex which has to be updated manually if ccTLDs change or get added. Tedious job!
- Very large regex so not very readable.

Comment: RE: tedious to update - Write a little code generator program to generate the regex based on the input data files.

Comment: True. With a good test harness this should be possible. We of course did no testing then...

Comment: The list from Mozilla seems pretty good actually -- it has *.uk to match .ac.uk .  You just have to figure out the format and interpret the rules correctly.

Comment: Worth noting that if you parse the mozilla list for ALL the possible tlds, the regex compilation fails. (on PHP at least)

Comment: I needed this for a couple projects, so I implemented it in Python and [opened it up on GitHub](http://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract). You can also query it via an HTTP endpoint on App Engine. Feel free to contribute!

Comment: There are [libraries](http://publicsuffix.org/learn/) based upon [Mozilla's Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org) that make getting any portion of the domain easy.

Comment: The Mozilla PSL now matches `*.uk`, so @pi.'s concern about it being unable to matching `ac.uk` no longer applies.

Comment: I think this answer is useless nowadays since restrictions for gTLDs have been removed by IANA and the list would need to be updated very frequently.

Comment: interesting approach, however it needed a bit change to work for me. this regex works fine if you are interested to find hostname (root domain address): /([^\.]+)\.(com|net|org|info)$/i

Answer (score 24):

A little late to the party, but:

```js
const urls = [
  'www.abc.au.uk',
  'https://github.com',
  'http://github.ca',
  'https://www.google.ru',
  'http://www.google.co.uk',
  'www.yandex.com',
  'yandex.ru',
  'yandex'
]

urls.forEach(url => console.log(url.replace(/.+\/\/|www.|\..+/g, '')))
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer. Thank you.

Comment: This **doesn't work**: for the input `www.mail.yahoo.co.in` the desired output is `mail.yahoo` but this outputs `mail`

Comment: That's more than fine, neither does the accepted answer, but this way is scalable and more dynamic. Whatever 10-20% of cases that you need to specifically match, where this approach comes short, you can hardcode as the accepted answer has done. It's an answer for the community, not for the OP, who's already received his answer 11 years ago.

Answer (score 16):

Extracting the Domain name accurately can be quite tricky mainly because the domain extension can contain 2 parts (like .com.au or .co.uk) and the subdomain (the prefix) may or may not be there. Listing all domain extensions is not an option because there are hundreds of these. EuroDNS.com for example lists over 800 domain name extensions.

I therefore wrote a short php function that uses 'parse_url()' and some observations about domain extensions to accurately extract the url components AND the domain name. The function is as follows:

```
function parse_url_all($url){
    $url = substr($url,0,4)=='http'? $url: 'http://'.$url;
    $d = parse_url($url);
    $tmp = explode('.',$d['host']);
    $n = count($tmp);
    if ($n>=2){
        if ($n==4 || ($n==3 && strlen($tmp[($n-2)])<=3)){
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n-3)].".".$tmp[($n-2)].".".$tmp[($n-1)];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n-3)];
        } else {
            $d['domain'] = $tmp[($n-2)].".".$tmp[($n-1)];
            $d['domainX'] = $tmp[($n-2)];
        }
    }
    return $d;
}
```

This simple function will work in almost every case. There are a few exceptions, but these are very rare.

To demonstrate / test this function you can use the following:

```
$urls = array('www.test.com', 'test.com', 'cp.test.com' .....);
echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>URL</th><th>Host</th><th>Domain</th><th>Domain X</th></tr>";
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $info = parse_url_all($url);
    echo "<tr><td>".$url."</td><td>".$info['host'].
    "</td><td>".$info['domain']."</td><td>".$info['domainX']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

The output will be as follows for the URL's listed:

[image]

As you can see, the domain name and the domain name without the extension are consistently extracted whatever the URL that is presented to the function.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Clinton said: "I therefore wrote a short php function that uses 'parse_url()' and some observations about domain extensions to accurately extract the url components AND the domain name."  Anyone have a JavaScript version of this function?

Comment: Good script. Is it still safe to use?

Comment: Thank you. I still use it on a number of applications that involve URL and domain checks and it works every time for me.

Comment: I dont have PHP to test your code, does `sub1.sub2.test.co.it` work in your case?

Comment: The code as it stands will work with 4 layers in the domain definition. You can easily extend this to 5 layers (as in your example) by changing the innermost if statement.

Comment: This is a nice little script that works for 95% of the cases. Thanks!  I just wanted to point out that it will fail if the domain is 3 or fewer letters long (www.cnn.com) so be careful if you just copy and paste.  The problem is that it's impossible to know if the domain is "www" with "cnn.com" as the TLD or "cnn" with "com" as the TLD.  In this case it's obvious, but you need to know all the TLDs to know for certain.

Answer (score 9):

```
/^(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.(?:com|au\.uk|co\.in)$/
```

Comment: I think the examples are there just to illustrate a general rule. This would only work on the input the OP gave.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways

**Using split**

Then just parse that string

```
var domain;
//find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
if (url.indexOf('://') > -1) {
    domain = url.split('/')[2];
} if (url.indexOf('//') === 0) {
    domain = url.split('/')[2];
} else {
    domain = url.split('/')[0];
}

//find & remove port number
domain = domain.split(':')[0];
```

**Using Regex**

```
 var r = /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/;
 "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343288/get-url".match(r)[1] 
 => stackoverflow.com
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works but needs to have protocol in the url

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any libraries, but the string manipulation of domain names is easy enough.

The hard part is knowing if the name is at the second or third level. For this you will need a data file you maintain (e.g. for .uk is is not always the third level, some organisations (e.g. bl.uk, jet.uk) exist at the second level).

The [source of Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) from Mozilla has such a data file, check the Mozilla licensing to see if you could reuse that.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible without using a TLD list to compare with as their exist many cases like http://www.db.de/ or http://bbc.co.uk/ that will be interpreted by a regex as the domains `db.de` (correct) and `co.uk` (wrong).

But even with that you won't have success if your list does not contain SLDs, too. URLs like https://liverpool.gov.uk.com/ would be interpreted as `gov.uk.com` (wrong).

Because of that, all browsers use Mozilla's Public Suffix List:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List

You can use it in your code by importing it through this URL:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/publicsuffix/list/master/public_suffix_list.dat

Feel free to extend my function to extract the domain name, only. It won't use regex and it is fast:
http://www.programmierer-forum.de/domainnamen-ermitteln-t244185.htm#3471878

Answer (score 3):

```
import urlparse

GENERIC_TLDS = [
    'aero', 'asia', 'biz', 'com', 'coop', 'edu', 'gov', 'info', 'int', 'jobs', 
    'mil', 'mobi', 'museum', 'name', 'net', 'org', 'pro', 'tel', 'travel', 'cat'
    ]

def get_domain(url):
    hostname = urlparse.urlparse(url.lower()).netloc
    if hostname == '':
        # Force the recognition as a full URL
        hostname = urlparse.urlparse('http://' + uri).netloc

    # Remove the 'user:passw', 'www.' and ':port' parts
    hostname = hostname.split('@')[-1].split(':')[0].lstrip('www.').split('.')

    num_parts = len(hostname)
    if (num_parts < 3) or (len(hostname[-1]) > 2):
        return '.'.join(hostname[:-1])
    if len(hostname[-2]) > 2 and hostname[-2] not in GENERIC_TLDS:
        return '.'.join(hostname[:-1])
    if num_parts >= 3:
        return '.'.join(hostname[:-2])
```

This code isn't guaranteed to work with all URLs and doesn't filter those that are grammatically correct but invalid like 'example.uk'.

However it'll do the job in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you want is:

```
google.com        -> google.com    -> google
www.google.com    -> google.com    -> google
google.co.uk      -> google.co.uk  -> google
www.google.co.uk  -> google.co.uk  -> google
www.google.org    -> google.org    -> google
www.google.org.uk -> google.org.uk -> google
```

Optional:

```
www.google.com     -> google.com    -> www.google
images.google.com  -> google.com    -> images.google
mail.yahoo.co.uk   -> yahoo.co.uk   -> mail.yahoo
mail.yahoo.com     -> yahoo.com     -> mail.yahoo
www.mail.yahoo.com -> yahoo.com     -> mail.yahoo
```

You don't need to construct an ever-changing regex as 99% of domains will be matched properly if you simply look at the 2nd last part of the name:

```
(co|com|gov|net|org)
```

If it is one of these, then you need to match 3 dots, else 2. Simple. Now, my regex wizardry is no match for that of some other SO'ers, so the best way I've found to achieve this is with some code, assuming you've already stripped off the path:

```
 my @d=split /\./,$domain;                # split the domain part into an array
 $c=@d;                                   # count how many parts
 $dest=$d[$c-2].'.'.$d[$c-1];             # use the last 2 parts
 if ($d[$c-2]=~m/(co|com|gov|net|org)/) { # is the second-last part one of these?
   $dest=$d[$c-3].'.'.$dest;              # if so, add a third part
 };
 print $dest;                             # show it
```

To just get the name, as per your question:

```
 my @d=split /\./,$domain;                # split the domain part into an array
 $c=@d;                                   # count how many parts
 if ($d[$c-2]=~m/(co|com|gov|net|org)/) { # is the second-last part one of these?
   $dest=$d[$c-3];                        # if so, give the third last
   $dest=$d[$c-4].'.'.$dest if ($c>3);    # optional bit
 } else {
   $dest=$d[$c-2];                        # else the second last
   $dest=$d[$c-3].'.'.$dest if ($c>2);    # optional bit 
 };
 print $dest;                             # show it
```

I like this approach because it's maintenance-free. Unless you want to validate that it's actually a legitimate domain, but that's kind of pointless because you're most likely only using this to process log files and an invalid domain wouldn't find its way in there in the first place.

If you'd like to match "unofficial" subdomains such as bozo.za.net, or bozo.au.uk, bozo.msf.ru just add (za|au|msf) to the regex.

I'd love to see someone do all of this using just a regex, I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just look for the word before .com (or other) (the order of the other list would be the opposite of the frequency see [here](https://www.icdsoft.com/blog/what-are-the-most-popular-tlds-domain-extensions/)

and take the first matching group
i.e.

```
window.location.host.match(/(\w|-)+(?=(\.(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co|ac|ie|co|ai|eu|ca|icu|top|xyz|tk|cn|ga|cf|nl|us|eu|de|hk|am|tv|bingo|blackfriday|gov|edu|mil|arpa|au|ru)(\.|\/|$)))/g)[0]
```

You can test it could by copying this line into the developers' console on any tab

This example works in the following cases:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`/[^w{3}\.]([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,65}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/gim`

usage of this javascript regex ignores www and following dot, while retaining the domain intact. also properly matches no www and cc tld

Answer (score 1):

I know you actually asked for Regex and were not specific to a language. But In Javascript you can do this like this. Maybe other languages can parse URL in a similar way.

### Easy Javascript solution

```js
const domain = (new URL(str)).hostname.replace("www.", "");
```

Leave this solution in js for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just have a string and not a window.location you could use...

```
String.prototype.toUrl = function(){

if(!this && 0 < this.length)
{
    return undefined;
}
var original = this.toString();
var s = original;
if(!original.toLowerCase().startsWith('http'))
{
    s = 'http://' + original;
}

s = this.split('/');

var protocol = s[0];
var host = s[2];
var relativePath = '';

if(s.length > 3){
    for(var i=3;i< s.length;i++)
    {
        relativePath += '/' + s[i];
    }
}

s = host.split('.');
var domain = s[s.length-2] + '.' + s[s.length-1];    

return {
    original: original,
    protocol: protocol,
    domain: domain,
    host: host,
    relativePath: relativePath,
    getParameter: function(param)
    {
        return this.getParameters()[param];
    },
    getParameters: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = this.original.slice(this.original.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
};};
```

How to use.

```
var str = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knopf?q=1&t=2";
var url = str.toUrl;

var host = url.host;
var domain = url.domain;
var original = url.original;
var relativePath = url.relativePath;
var paramQ = url.getParameter('q');
var paramT = url.getParamter('t');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a certain purpose I did this quick Python function yesterday. It returns domain from URL. It's quick and doesn't need any input file listing stuff. However, I don't pretend it works in all cases, but it really does the job I needed for a simple text mining script.

Output looks like this :

http://www.google.co.uk => google.co.uk
http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m04s34rqh567ij78k_250.gif => tumblr.com

```
def getDomain(url):    
        parts = re.split("\/", url)
        match = re.match("([\w\-]+\.)*([\w\-]+\.\w{2,6}$)", parts[2]) 
        if match != None:
            if re.search("\.uk", parts[2]): 
                match = re.match("([\w\-]+\.)*([\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+\.\w{2,6}$)", parts[2])
            return match.group(2)
        else: return ''
```

Seems to work pretty well.
However, it has to be modified to remove domain extensions on output as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)/i
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true of regexen, which are notorious for being opaque line noise to most. Here, too, it's not especially clear that it solves the entirety of the problem, and since there are answers that *do*, and do so well, and with excellent explanations….

Answer (score 0):

1. how is this

   `=((?:(?:(?:http)s?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.?)*(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+))\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})`
   (you may want to add "\/" to end of pattern
2. if your goal is to rid url's passed in as a param you may add the equal sign as the first char, like:

   =((?:(?:(?:http)s?:)?//)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+).?)*(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)).[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}/)

   and replace with "/"

The goal of this example to get rid of any domain name regardless of the form it appears in.
(i.e. to ensure url parameters don't incldue domain names to avoid xss attack)

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are very nice, but all will fails sometime.
So i know it is not common to link something else, already answered elsewhere, but you'll find that you have to not waste your time into impossible thing.
This because domains like *mydomain.co.uk* there is no way to know if an extracted domain is correct.
If you speak about to extract by URLs, something that ever have http or https or nothing in front (but if it is possible nothing in front, you have to remove

```
filter_var($url, filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
```

here below, because FILTER_VALIDATE_URL do not recognize as url a string that do not begin with http, so may remove it, and you can also achieve with something stupid like this, that never will fail:

```
$url = strtolower('hTTps://www.example.com/w3/forum/index.php');

if( filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && substr($url, 0, 4) == 'http' )
{
// array order is !important
$domain = str_replace(array("http://www.","https://www.","http://","https://"), array("","","",""), $url);
$spos = strpos($domain,'/');
if($spos !== false)
{
 $domain = substr($domain, 0, $spos);
} } else { $domain = "can't extract a domain"; }

echo $domain;
```

[Check FILTER_VALIDATE_URL default behavior here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

But, if you want to check a domain for his validity, and ALWAYS be sure that the extracted value is correct, then you have to check against an array of valid top domains, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566657/6399448
or you'll NEVER be sure that the extracted string is the correct domain. Unfortunately, all the answers here sometime will fails.

P.s the unique answer that make sense here seem to me this (i did not read it before sorry. It provide the same solution, even if do not provide an example as mine above mentioned or linked):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/569219/6399448

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the best way to do this is using the [tld-extract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tld-extract) npm package. Check out an example at the [following link](https://runkit.com/anweshgangula/63e26ebf27932100080ae02d).

Below is the code for the same:

```js
var tldExtract = require("tld-extract")

const urls = [
  'http://www.mail.yahoo.co.in/',
  'https://mail.yahoo.com/',
  'https://www.abc.au.uk',
  'https://github.com',
  'http://github.ca',
  'https://www.google.ru',
  'https://google.co.uk',
  'https://www.yandex.com',
  'https://yandex.ru',
]

const tldList = [];

urls.forEach(url => tldList.push(tldExtract(url)))

console.log({tldList})
```

which results in the following output:

```json
0: Object {tld: "co.in", domain: "yahoo.co.in", sub: "www.mail"}
1: Object {tld: "com", domain: "yahoo.com", sub: "mail"}
2: Object {tld: "uk", domain: "au.uk", sub: "www.abc"}
3: Object {tld: "com", domain: "github.com", sub: ""}
4: Object {tld: "ca", domain: "github.ca", sub: ""}
5: Object {tld: "ru", domain: "google.ru", sub: "www"}
6: Object {tld: "co.uk", domain: "google.co.uk", sub: ""}
7: Object {tld: "com", domain: "yandex.com", sub: "www"}
8: Object {tld: "ru", domain: "yandex.ru", sub: ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a [custom function](https://amitd.co/code/javascript/get-domain-without-subdomain) which works in most of the cases:

```js
function getDomainWithoutSubdomain(url) {
    const urlParts = new URL(url).hostname.split('.')

    return urlParts
        .slice(0)
        .slice(-(urlParts.length === 4 ? 3 : 2))
        .join('.')

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a list of what domain prefixes and suffixes can be removed. For example:

Prefixes:

- `www.`

Suffixes:

- `.com`
- `.co.in`
- `.au.uk`

Comment: works only for the samples and maintaining such lists does not scale

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $url = $ARGV[0];
if($url =~ /([^:]*:\/\/)?([^\/]*\.)*([^\/\.]+)\.[^\/]+/g) {
  print $3;
}
```

Comment: if you used other characters than a forward slash for the match operator, then you wouldn't need to have to have so many escape characters and can make the regex more readable, e.g. `$url =~ m{([^:]*://)?([^/]*\.)*([^/\.]+)\.[^/]+}`

not sure you want the looping operator (/g) either?

Comment: True, although the big problem with my response is that it won't work for foreign domains since they don't follow the standard US format "xxx.(com|edu|org|etc)".  Sot telegraph.co.uk won't match.  Makes me think that you really do need to explicitly list out all of the various country codes in order to match something like that.

Comment: or since other people have already figured this stuff out, just use a module to do it, such as URI::Find - http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::Find or if you just want a regex then http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::URI

Comment: Of course, but when someone asks for a regex, it's always fun to work it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Just for knowledge:

```
'http://api.livreto.co/books'.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)([a-z]{3}[0-9]?\.)?(\w+)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?.*$/, '$3$4$5');

# returns livreto.co
```

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is seeking a regex solution but in every attempt it won't work to cover everything

I decided to write this method in Python which only works with urls that have a subdomain (i.e. www.mydomain.co.uk) and not multiple level subdomains like `www.mail.yahoo.com`

```
def urlextract(url):
  url_split=url.split(".")
  if len(url_split) <= 2:
      raise Exception("Full url required with subdomain:",url)
  return {'subdomain': url_split[0], 'domain': url_split[1], 'suffix': ".".join(url_split[2:])}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say we have this: http://google.com

and you only want the domain name

```
let url = http://google.com;
let domainName = url.split("://")[1];
console.log(domainName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this
(.)(.*?)(.)
then just extract the leading and end points. 
Easy, right?