# How can I strip the subdomain and .com/.org etc from a domain in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dns

I want to get just the domain name(yahoo, google, stackoverflow) from the domain in javascript. How can I easily pull just this out and drop any subdomain and any extension?

See comment, I need it to work for any domain if possible.

Comment: I need it to work for any domain and TLD extension.  www.test.com or test.com or something.test.co.uk.

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem if you need any TLD. you need a database of rules for all of the different ccTLD's, and even then there are exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

See [how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url)

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
"www.google.com".match(/\.?([^.]+)\.[^.]+.?$/)[1]
```

Comment: almost, but fails for cases like 'google.com.br' (http://jsfiddle.net/dvHmJ/). Better answers in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253136/how-to-get-domain-name-only-using-javascript/8253221#8253221

Answer (score 1):

```
var domain = 'http://www.google.com/';
var parts = domain.toString().split('.'.toString());
parts[parts.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 1):

i needed to do this and whipped up something simple that accounted for my use case

```
function stripSubDomainAndTLD (domain) {
    return domain.replace(/^(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.)??([a-z0-9\-]+)(?:\.com|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.ws|\.in|\.me|\.co\.uk|\.co|\.org\.uk|\.ltd\.uk|\.plc\.uk|\.me\.uk|\.edu|\.mil|\.br\.com|\.cn\.com|\.eu\.com|\.hu\.com|\.no\.com|\.qc\.com|\.sa\.com|\.se\.com|\.se\.net|\.us\.com|\.uy\.com|\.ac|\.co\.ac|\.gv\.ac|\.or\.ac|\.ac\.ac|\.af|\.am|\.as|\.at|\.ac\.at|\.co\.at|\.gv\.at|\.or\.at|\.asn\.au|\.com\.au|\.edu\.au|\.org\.au|\.net\.au|\.id\.au|\.be|\.ac\.be|\.adm\.br|\.adv\.br|\.am\.br|\.arq\.br|\.art\.br|\.bio\.br|\.cng\.br|\.cnt\.br|\.com\.br|\.ecn\.br|\.eng\.br|\.esp\.br|\.etc\.br|\.eti\.br|\.fm\.br|\.fot\.br|\.fst\.br|\.g12\.br|\.gov\.br|\.ind\.br|\.inf\.br|\.jor\.br|\.lel\.br|\.med\.br|\.mil\.br|\.net\.br|\.nom\.br|\.ntr\.br|\.odo\.br|\.org\.br|\.ppg\.br|\.pro\.br|\.psc\.br|\.psi\.br|\.rec\.br|\.slg\.br|\.tmp\.br|\.tur\.br|\.tv\.br|\.vet\.br|\.zlg\.br|\.br|\.ab\.ca|\.bc\.ca|\.mb\.ca|\.nb\.ca|\.nf\.ca|\.ns\.ca|\.nt\.ca|\.on\.ca|\.pe\.ca|\.qc\.ca|\.sk\.ca|\.yk\.ca|\.ca|\.cc|\.ac\.cn|\.com\.cn|\.edu\.cn|\.gov\.cn|\.org\.cn|\.bj\.cn|\.sh\.cn|\.tj\.cn|\.cq\.cn|\.he\.cn|\.nm\.cn|\.ln\.cn|\.jl\.cn|\.hl\.cn|\.js\.cn|\.zj\.cn|\.ah\.cn|\.gd\.cn|\.gx\.cn|\.hi\.cn|\.sc\.cn|\.gz\.cn|\.yn\.cn|\.xz\.cn|\.sn\.cn|\.gs\.cn|\.qh\.cn|\.nx\.cn|\.xj\.cn|\.tw\.cn|\.hk\.cn|\.mo\.cn|\.cn|\.cx|\.cz|\.de|\.dk|\.fo|\.com\.ec|\.tm\.fr|\.com\.fr|\.asso\.fr|\.presse\.fr|\.fr|\.gf|\.gs|\.co\.il|\.net\.il|\.ac\.il|\.k12\.il|\.gov\.il|\.muni\.il|\.ac\.in|\.co\.in|\.org\.in|\.ernet\.in|\.gov\.in|\.net\.in|\.res\.in|\.is|\.it|\.ac\.jp|\.co\.jp|\.go\.jp|\.or\.jp|\.ne\.jp|\.ac\.kr|\.co\.kr|\.go\.kr|\.ne\.kr|\.nm\.kr|\.or\.kr|\.li|\.lt|\.lu|\.asso\.mc|\.tm\.mc|\.com\.mm|\.org\.mm|\.net\.mm|\.edu\.mm|\.gov\.mm|\.ms|\.nl|\.no|\.nu|\.pl|\.ro|\.org\.ro|\.store\.ro|\.tm\.ro|\.firm\.ro|\.www\.ro|\.arts\.ro|\.rec\.ro|\.info\.ro|\.nom\.ro|\.nt\.ro|\.se|\.si|\.com\.sg|\.org\.sg|\.net\.sg|\.gov\.sg|\.sk|\.st|\.tf|\.ac\.th|\.co\.th|\.go\.th|\.mi\.th|\.net\.th|\.or\.th|\.tm|\.to|\.com\.tr|\.edu\.tr|\.gov\.tr|\.k12\.tr|\.net\.tr|\.org\.tr|\.com\.tw|\.org\.tw|\.net\.tw|\.ac\.uk|\.uk\.com|\.uk\.net|\.gb\.com|\.gb\.net|\.vg|\.sh|\.kz|\.ch|\.info|\.ua|\.gov|\.name|\.pro|\.ie|\.hk|\.com\.hk|\.org\.hk|\.net\.hk|\.edu\.hk|\.us|\.tk|\.cd|\.by|\.ad|\.lv|\.eu\.lv|\.bz|\.es|\.jp|\.cl|\.ag|\.mobi|\.eu|\.co\.nz|\.org\.nz|\.net\.nz|\.maori\.nz|\.iwi\.nz|\.io|\.la|\.md|\.sc|\.sg|\.vc|\.tw|\.travel|\.my|\.se|\.tv|\.pt|\.com\.pt|\.edu\.pt|\.asia|\.fi|\.com\.ve|\.net\.ve|\.fi|\.org\.ve|\.web\.ve|\.info\.ve|\.co\.ve|\.tel|\.im|\.gr|\.ru|\.net\.ru|\.org\.ru|\.hr|\.com\.hr)$/, '$1');
}
```

mainly i just wanted to remove all subdomains, unfortunately this isn't 100% for some of the new TLD's but it works pretty well, and you can always add to the regex.

http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/TzjJE/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the window.location object to support MLD (Mid Level Domain).

```
window.location.mld = function() {
    return window.location.hostname.split('.').reverse()[1];
}();
```

Use it like this:
    `window.location.mld`

Which will output `google` if you're on `www.google.com`

Comment: Huh. Why would you add this function to the location object instead of somewhere else?

Comment: Because it's a part of the url, the rest of the methods of window.location is too, so in my opinion it fits.

Comment: Wouldn't it better in the URL prototype object, then? (Is there something like this? My JavaScript knowledge is a bit rusty.)

Comment: There is nothing like the URL object, the nearest thing is actually the Location object.