# Get the domain name of the subdomain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns, subdomain

How i can get the domain name `example.com` from the set of possible subdomains `sub1.example.com` `sub2.example.com` `sub3.example.com`  using javascript ...?

Comment: What about `sub1.example.co.uk`? http://publicsuffix.org/

Comment: This is one of the options, thanks for the correction

Comment: Do you want the domain name for sub3.example.com.ua to be example.com or example.com.ua?

Comment: `example.com.ua` I need to allow the use of a script on a specific domain and its subdomains, while prohibiting its use in other domains. So I need to make a selection for the domain name.

Comment: And what would it be for, for example, [`meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/`](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and [`http://cooking.stackexchange.com/`](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: it will be `stackexchange.com`

Comment: Use location.host and cut off subdomains..check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253136/how-to-get-domain-name-only-using-javascript

Comment: I'm not great with regex, but I'm thinking you need something like /[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,6}?\.?[a-z]{2,6}/i

Comment: @Llepwryd: No. Regex is not needed, and this one will not do the expected.

Comment: Thank you all! The issue is solved!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = parts.shift();
var upperleveldomain = parts.join('.');
```

To get only the second-level-domain, you might use

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
var sndleveldomain = parts.slice(-2).join('.');
```

Comment: @Bergi - I know the OP was meant for domain names and not IP addresses, but I just wanted to point out that while this works great for named addresses, it doesn't work for IP based addresses and incorrectly breaks them up (i.e. 127.0.0.1 returns "0.1").

Comment: @johntrepreneur: You mean when the `hostname` is an IP address? Yeah, but I can't think of a result that would make much sense in that case… should it be returned unmodified?

Comment: @Bergi - yeah hostname is IP address as uncommon as that is (except in development). Yea, I just checked that it has 3 dots (4 parts after split) and that the hostname (minus dots) was only digits.

`if (arrHostname.length == 4 && /^\d+$/.test(hostname.replace(/\./g, ''))) // is IP address; return hostname unmodified`

Comment: @Bergi - sorry to confuse you. This OP is really targeted at domain names and not domain IP's so my comment doesn't really apply. I just had implemented it and noticed it wasn't working in my case using 127.0.0.1 so I thought I'd mention it even though it's not totally relavant to OP.

Comment: @HankYang: `co.uk` is the subdomain (second level domain), my snippet works just as well for that. If you are looking for effective second level domains, you will have to incorporate the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) in your application.

Comment: wont this run into issues with TLDs like `co.uk` as @Bergi mentioned??

Comment: @BugWhisperer As mentioned, `co.uk` is not a TLD.

Comment: If anything, isn't `co` by itself the SLD, whereas the TLD is `uk`??

Comment: @oldboy See my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470476/9638991) and https://publicsuffix.org/ for details about how to fix issues with public suffixes (e.g. `co.uk`)

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer will work to get the second level domain. However, there is something called "public suffixes" that you may want to take into account. Otherwise, you may get unexpected and erroneous results.

For example, take the domain `www.amazon.co.uk`.
If you just try getting the second level domain, you'll end up with `co.uk`, which is probably not what you want. That's because `co.uk` is a "public suffix", which means it's essentially a top level domain. Here's the definition of a public suffix, taken from https://publicsuffix.org:

> A "public suffix" is one under which Internet users can (or historically could) directly register names.

If this is a crucial part of your application, I would look into something like `psl` (https://github.com/lupomontero/psl) for domain parsing. It works in nodejs and the browser, and it's tested on Mozilla's maintained public suffix list.

Here's a quick example from their README:

```js
var psl = require('psl');

// TLD with some 2-level rules.
psl.get('uk.com'); // null);
psl.get('example.uk.com'); // 'example.uk.com');
psl.get('b.example.uk.com'); // 'example.uk.com');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is faster

```
const firstDotIndex = subDomain.indexOf('.');
const domain = subDomain.substring(firstDotIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution is explained here http://rossscrivener.co.uk/blog/javascript-get-domain-exclude-subdomain
From above link

```
var domain = (function(){
   var i=0,domain=document.domain,p=domain.split('.'),s='_gd'+(new Date()).getTime();
   while(i<(p.length-1) && document.cookie.indexOf(s+'='+s)==-1){
      domain = p.slice(-1-(++i)).join('.');
      document.cookie = s+"="+s+";domain="+domain+";";
   }
   document.cookie = s+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain="+domain+";";
   return domain;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function getDomain() {
        const hostnameArray = window.location.hostname.split('.')
        const numberOfSubdomains = hostnameArray.length - 2
        return hostnameArray.length === 2 ? window.location.hostname : hostnameArray.slice(numberOfSubdomains).join('.')
    }
    console.log(getDomain());
```

This will remove all subdomains, so "a.b.c.d.test.com" will become "test.com"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify if a specific subdomain exists

```
var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
if(parts.includes('subdomain_to_search_here')){
   //yes
}else{
   //no
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some more robust version, which is independent of the subdomain count

```
function getDomain() {
   const hostname = window.location.hostname.split('.');
   hostname.reverse();
   return `${hostname[1]}.${hostname[0]}`;
}
```