# Getting domain name from subdomain localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost

How do I get the domain name from a subdomain?

Like:

URL -> Output
m.gigabyte.com -> gigabyte.com
forums.localhost -> localhost

I have tried:

```
var domain = window.location.host.split( '.' );
window.location = 'http://' + domain[1] + domain[2] + window.location.pathname;
```

But it doesn't seem to work on localhost. I just want to strip off the subdomain and not the `.com, .org, .net`'s anymore...

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367376/get-the-domain-name-of-the-subdomain-javascript also read http://www.interactivebynature.com/2011.04.09.remove-subdomain-from-url-with-javascript

Comment: What about domains like `.co.uk`? Sometimes it can be very hard to know where primary domain stops and subdomain starts.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var subdomain = 'aaaa.bbb.ccc.com';
var dotIndex = subdomain.indexOf('.');
var maindomain = subdomain.substr(dotIndex+1);
```