# Get website name from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, filtering

I was wondering if there was a way to get the website name from the URL, using either JavaScript, or Node-JS.

Here is an example:

```
https://www.google.com     → google
http://www.facebook.com.au → facebook
duckduckgo.com             → duckduckgo
material.io                → material
```

I was thinking about filtering out common things like `.com`, `www.` etc, but then there are country codes, like `.au`, `.cn`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract hostname name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-hostname-name-from-string)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you question seems opinion based, and I am afraid it will be closed by moderator. Please post some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Or duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942552/get-second-level-domain-name-from-url also has a good solution

Comment: Pretty much answers it :)
Is there any place to find all of the TLDs though?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution,

`function fetch_domain(url) {
    var str = url;
    var n = str.indexOf("://");
    if(n>-1){
        n = n+"://".length;
    }else{
        n=0;
    }
    var x = str.indexOf("/www.");
    if(x>-1){
        str = str.replace("/www.", "/");
    }
    return str.slice(n, str.indexOf("."));
}`

Thanks!