# Subdomains Laravel Routing and Vue.js

Tags: subdomain, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-router

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`, `vue.js 2.3` and `vue-router`.

## Current situation

When `example.com` is hit, `Laravel` returns the `app` view which starts the `Vue.app`

#### web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('app');
});
```

#### app.js

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: App },
];

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data () {
        return {}
    },
});
```

#### App.vue

```
export default {
    ...
}
```

## What I'm trying to do

If `usa.example.com` is typed, I would like the `alert()` in my `App.vue` to show `usa`.

If `italy.example.com` is typed, I would like the `alert()` in my `App.vue` to show `italy`.

I read the documentation of `vue-router` but I'm not sure wether it is a `Laravel` issue, a `Vue` issue or both.

#### App.vue

```
export default {
    ....
    created() {
        alert('subdomain is ' + $route.params.subdomain)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueRouter doesn't keep track of the subdomain.

But, you can get the subdomain from the `location` and use that in your component's `created` method:

```
created() {
  let subdomain = location.hostname.split('.').shift();
  alert('subdomain is ' + subdomain);
}
```

The above code is based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367376/get-the-domain-name-of-the-subdomain-javascript).