# Javascript return true if a string contains subdomain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API that returns a domain to my front end.

This domain is the string format.

```
For eg: "google.com" / "google.co.ok"
or "test.google.com"/ "test.google.co.ok:
```

Notice that the string does not contain any protocol.

I want to write a method that parses the string and returns true if the string contains a subdomain.

In the above 2 examples, the method should return true for **test.google.com or test.google.co.ok**

EDIT: If it were python, i would write something like below. But hoping something similat was available in JS.

```
from tld import get_tld, get_fld

get_tld("www.google.co.uk", fix_protocol=True)
# 'co.uk'

get_fld("www.google.co.uk", fix_protocol=True)
# 'google.co.uk'
```

Comment: Since there's no protocol, maybe something like 
`"word.domain.co.uk/something".split("/")[0].split(",").length > 2`

Comment: @Dexygen See my edit. I know how to get answer if I were to use Python

Comment: Have a look at [Get the domain name of the subdomain Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13367376/1048572) then. Is that enough to answer your question?

Comment: @DanielSzabo's solution seems to work. can you add that as answer please

Comment: You didn't write a Python method, you used a method from a library

Comment: I think you need to define what a "subdomain" is (or is not), more rigorously.  [rfc1034 section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-3.1) says _A domain is a subdomain of another domain if it
is contained within that domain._  This suggests that even "com" is a subdomain of the root domain " ".

Comment: Did you look into the implementation of [the python library you were using](https://pypi.org/project/tld/)?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, `example.com` technically is only a relative domain, which usually refers to the unambiguous `example.com.` domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple JavaScript libraries available that can be used the same way you're using `tld`. [psl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl) is older but still has millions of weekly downloads.

You could use `psl` and implement something like this:

```js
import { parse } from "psl";

function hasSubdomain(str) {
  const { subdomain } = parse(str);
  
  return subdomain !== null;
}

hasSubdomain("www.google.com") // true
hasSubdomain("google.co.uk") // false
```

Feel free to clone and edit this [example on RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/rlw4lj03ahi7) as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing.  Since there's no protocol, maybe something like:

```
"word.domain.com"
  .split(".").length > 2 // true

"domain.com"
  .split(".").length > 2 // false

"www.domain.co.uk"
  .split(".").length > 2 // uh-oh
```

You'll likely need to parse out "www" and [second-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Second-level_domains) (".co", ".gc", etc).

Comment: For those "multi-part top-level domains" (I'd rather call them "effective" tlds), see the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org)

Comment: hmmm..parsing out www makes sense..but keeping track of second-level domain could be challenging

Answer (score -2):

You can use `RegExp` to perform string manipulation. Please take a look at the following snippet and run the code and see the results from different test cases covering most of the possibilities. Let me know if it's helpful.

```js
function subDomain(url) {
  // REMOVE LEADING AND TRAILING WHITE SPACE 
  url = url.replace(new RegExp(/^\s+/), ""); // START
  url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\s+$/), ""); // END

  // CONVERT BACK SLASHES TO FORWARD SLASHES
  url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\\/g), "/");

  // REMOVES 'www.' FROM THE START OF THE STRING
  url = url.replace(new RegExp(/^www\./i), "");

  // REMOVE STRING FROM FIRST FORWARD SLASH ON
  url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\/(.*)/), "");

  // REMOVES '.??.??' OR '.???.??' FROM END - e.g. '.CO.UK', '.COM.AU'
  if (url.match(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2}$/i))) {
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2}$/i), "");

    // REMOVES '.??' or '.???' or '.????' FROM END - e.g. '.US', '.COM', '.INFO'
  } else if (url.match(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i))) {
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i), "");
  }

  // CHECK TO SEE IF THERE IS A DOT '.' LEFT
  var subDomain = url.match(new RegExp(/\./g)) ? true : false;

  return subDomain;
}

const subdomainInput = "test.google.com";
const subdomainInputWithPath = "test.google.com/test";
const subdomainInputWithPathWithWS = "    test.google.com    ";
const subdomainInputWithWS = "   test.google.com    ";
const subdomainInputWithQueryString = "test.google.com/test?token=33333";
const noSubInput = "google.com"
const noSubInputWithPath = "google.com/search"
const noSubInputWithPathWithQueryString = "google.com/search?token=ttttttt"
console.log("Test Run\n")
conosle.log("With subdomain test cases")
console.log(`subdomainInput: ${subDomain(subdomainInput)}`);
console.log(`subdomainInputWithPath: ${subDomain(subdomainInputWithPath)}`);
console.log(`subdomainInputWithWS: ${subDomain(subdomainInputWithWS)}`);
console.log(`subdomainInputWithPathWithWS: ${subDomain(subdomainInputWithPathWithWS)}`);
console.log(`subdomainInputWithQueryString: ${subDomain(subdomainInputWithQueryString)}`);

conosle.log("Without subdomain test cases")
console.log(`noSubInput: ${subDomain(noSubInput)}`);
console.log(`noSubInput: ${subDomain(noSubInput)}`);
console.log(`noSubInputWithPath: ${subDomain(noSubInputWithPath)}`);
console.log(`noSubInputWithPathWithQueryString: ${subDomain(noSubInputWithPathWithQueryString)}`);
```

return(subDomain);

}