# get hostname but check if hostname has subdomain

Tags: javascript

I have to get a hostname without suffix and without subdomain.

exp:

```
URL: https://my-domain.com
URL2: https://my-domain.store.com
```

So I need only the my-domain how can I get this ?

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/

Comment: `const url = new URL('http://example.com/path/index.html?param=value'); url.hostname`

Comment: @Yarin_007 it only gives the whole domain, including subdomain

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*without subdomain*", in `my-domain.store.com` the `my-domain` is the subdomain? You actually want to get `store`?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/)

```
const url = new URL('http://example.com/path/index.html?param=value');
console.log(url.hostname) // gives example.com
```

and if it has a subdomain:

```
function getDomain(hostname) {
   hostname = hostname.split('.');
   hostname.reverse();
   return `${hostname[1]}.${hostname[0]}`;
}

url = new URL('http://test.example.com/path/index.html?param=value');
getDomain(url.hostname) // gives example.com

url = new URL('http://example.com/path/index.html?param=value');
getDomain(url.hostname) // gives example.com
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71268543/4935162)

Comment: What's the point of the `reverse()`?

Comment: it's to deal with multiple sub-domains, it always takes the last 2 zones. he could have implemented it differently, with like hostname[hostname.length-1]

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, `${hostname.at(-2)}.${hostname.at(-1)}` would've been more clear. However, a more simple (and more correct, since not all hostnames have at least 2 zones) way to achieve that would be `return hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.')`

Comment: Definitely agree, there are a couple of similar examples there