# How to extract the TLD from the URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to extract the TLD from the URL but it's giving me the whole URL instead.
For example https://www.google.com.uk -> .com.uk.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
       var href = $(this).attr("href");
       alert(href)// It gives me the whole link of website
    if(href.search(".com.uk")){
        alert("This website is AUTHENTIC!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Not AUTHENTIC!")
    }
```

Comment: `.co.uk` is not a TLD, it's a second-level domain. It is at best a [eTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) which requires custom cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get domain name only using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253136/how-to-get-domain-name-only-using-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

To get the last piece of a domain, such as `com` in `example.com`, use something like:

```
const tld = window.location.origin.split('.').pop();
```

However, eTLDs like `co.uk` need special cases. If you want to hardcode a check for `.co.uk`:

```
const isUK = window.location.origin.endsWith('.co.uk');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `URL` class for that:

```
var url = new URL(href);
console.log(url.pathname); // /some/path
```

Additionally the resulting `url` object has more useful properties and makes the browser do the string parsing part, so you do not have have to fiddle around with regular expressions in most cases.

To extract the TLD hostname you can use something like that:

```
url.hostname.split(/\./).slice(-2).join('.');
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Comment: That RegExp doesn't capture anything (no parentheses) and, if it would, it would extract only the last part (i.e. `.uk`, not `.com.uk`)

Comment: I have added some parentheses to make it capture something…

Comment: Have you tried testing that RegExp (or the other way you mention) against `www.google.com.uk` ?