# how to replace domain name by javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the domain without the hostname from the URL?

I have the following list

```
const value1 = 'https://localhost:4200/~';
const value2 = 'https://hoge.com/~';
const value3 = 'https://www.hoge.com/~';
const value4 = 'https://wwwtest.hoge.com/~';
const value5 = 'https://www-test.hoge.com/~';
```

the answer i'm looking for

```
'localhost:4200/~'; //value1 
'hoge.com/~'; //value2
'hoge.com/~'; //value3
'hoge.com/~'; //value4
'hoge.com/~'; //value5
```

I tried the following method, but the answer was not correct.

```
function hogeReplace(value: string): string {
  return value.replace(/^https?:\/\/|www.*\./g, '');
}

console.log(hogeReplace(value1)); // localhost:4200/~
console.log(hogeReplace(value2)); // hoge.com/~
console.log(hogeReplace(value3)); // com/~
console.log(hogeReplace(value4)); // com/~
console.log(hogeReplace(value5)); // com/~
```

someone answer?

Comment: Just use the substring method to remove the first 8 characters

Comment: I also want to remove the hostname

Comment: You may want to start with [parsing the url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and then split it up instead of using a regex

Comment: It sounds like you've not looked at the vast amount of information [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) can give you. All those URLs have the same top level domain.

Comment: _"domain without the hostname"_...  aren't they essentially the same thing? TLDs are entirely subjective and would be difficult to parse out. How do you tell the difference between a `.com`, `.co.uk`, `.museum`, or `.i.paid.good.money.for.this`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get domain name only using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8253136/283366)

Comment: without the hostname? You mean without the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step by step solution:

I am assuming by "domain name" you mean specifically hoge.com, or any two element domain name?

In which case my recommendation would be:

1. Chop off the https.
2. Break up the remaining items by "/". Everything after the first "/" can stay.
3. What is before that first "/", slice into pieces by ".". Keep only the last two of those.

```js
function hogeReplace(value) {
  const withoutHttp = value.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');
  const segments = withoutHttp.split("/");
  const hostname = segments[0]
  const localPath = segments.slice(1).join("/")
  const domainName = hostname.replace(/^www[a-zA-Z~-]*/,"")
  return domainName + "/" + localPath
}

console.log(hogeReplace("https://localhost:4200/~"))
console.log(hogeReplace("https://hoge.com/~"))
console.log(hogeReplace("https://www.hoge.com/~"))
console.log(hogeReplace("https://wwwtest.hoge.com/~"))
console.log(hogeReplace("https://www-test.hoge.com/~"))
console.log(hogeReplace("https://www.hoge.co.uk/~"))
```

Comment: What about `hoge.co.uk`?

Comment: Yes it won't work for that. However it looks like he is only interested in hoge.com.

Comment: Rather than use a regex, I'd be more inclined to parse the string as a `URL` and extract the `hostname`. That way you won't get false positives for things like credentials

Comment: @shibata if that is actually a requirement, then your question is far too broad right now. It needs **a lot** more detail

Comment: thx Eureka. but I also needed the following pattern `hoge.co.uk`

Comment: What is that pattern? ANY 3 words? Or Hoge + anything? 4 words? 5 words? Or only .com and .co.uk?

Comment: sorry! If there is `www~`, I want to remove it

Comment: OK try the updated version!

Comment: thank you Eureka!!!!! I love you !!!!!!!!