# Regular expression to retrieve domain.tld

Tags: java, regex

I'm need a regular expression in Java that I can use to retrieve the domain.tld part from any url. So https://foo.com/bar, http://www.foo.com#bar, http://bar.foo.com will all return foo.com.

I wrote this regex, but it's matching the whole url

```
Pattern.compile("[.]?.*[.x][a-z]{2,3}");
```

I'm not sure I'm matching the "." character right. I tried "." but I get an error from netbeans.

**Update:**

The tld is not limited to 2 or 3 characters, and http://www.foo.co.uk/bar should return foo.co.uk.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Comment: Actually not an exact duplicate, as the other question tries to remove the tld part as well as some second-level parts like ".co.uk". But the only difference is whether you capture that part. I guess he'd want http://www.foo.co.uk/ to give foo.co.uk

Comment: do you know there are four letter TLDs like "info" and "name"? I think you missed that, because you got that "{2,3}" in your regular expression.

Secondly, if you want to match the dot, you have to escape it like this "\\."

Comment: Just read that there are even ".museum" and ".travel" tlds.

Comment: Good catch. I would want foo.co.uk/bar to return foo.co.uk.

Comment: I found this answer very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4820675/1740705.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the java.net.URI class to extract the host name, and then use a regex to extract the last two parts of the host uri.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RunIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?([^.]+\\.[^.]+)");

        String[] urls = new String[] {
                "https://foo.com/bar",
                "http://www.foo.com#bar",
                "http://bar.foo.com"
        };

        for (String url:urls) {
            URI uri = new URI(url);
            //eg: uri.getHost() will return "www.foo.com"
            Matcher m = p.matcher(uri.getHost());
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
foo.com
foo.com
foo.com
```

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing.

Comment: An what about domain names like foobar.co.uk?

Answer (score 10):

This is harder than you might imagine.  Your example https://foo.com/bar, has a comma in it, which is a valid URL character.  Here is a great post about some of the troubles:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/

```
https?://([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|])
```

Is a good starting point

Some listings from "Mastering Regular Expressions" on this topic:

http://regex.info/listing.cgi?ed=3&p=207

@sjobe

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'https?://([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|])'
>>> url = re.compile(pattern)
>>> url.match('http://news.google.com/').groups()
('news.google.com/',)
>>> url.match('not a url').groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
>>> url.match('http://google.com/').groups()
('google.com/',)
>>> url.match('http://google.com').groups()
('google.com',)
```

sorry the example is in python not java, it's more brief.  Java requires some extraneous escaping of the regex.

Comment: I dont think he meant the comma to be part of the url , he was just separating a list

Comment: That's my point, it's ambiguous.  How should the regex determine if the comma is part of the URL or not?

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway, as he's interested in "domain.tld" part of an http URL. There's no comma in that part.

Comment: I tried that regular expression [added a ')' at the end]

https?://([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|])

but it's not matching any url's. I'm trying "http://news.google.com" and "http://www.google.com"

Comment: Your codinghorror link is broken. I'm supposing this it. http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/

Answer (score 6):

If the string contains a valid URL then you could use a regex like (Perl quoting):

```
/^
(?:\w+:\/\/)?
[^:?#\/\s]*?

(
[^.\s]+
\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|org\.au|com\.au|___etc___)
)

(?:[:?#\/]|$)
/xi;
```

Results:

```
url: https://foo.com/bar
matched: foo.com
url: http://www.foo.com#bar
matched: foo.com
url: http://bar.foo.com
matched: foo.com
url: ftp://foo.com
matched: foo.com
url: ftp://www.foo.co.uk?bar
matched: foo.co.uk
url: ftp://www.foo.co.uk:8080/bar
matched: foo.co.uk
```

For Java it would be quoted something like:

```
"^(?:\\w+://)?[^:?#/\\s]*?([^.\\s]+\\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|co\\.uk|org\\.uk|ac\\.uk|org\\.au|com\\.au|___etc___))(?:[:?#/]|$)"
```

Of course you'll need to replace the ***etc*** part.

Example Perl script:

```
use strict;

my @test = qw(
    https://foo.com/bar
    http://www.foo.com#bar
    http://bar.foo.com
    ftp://foo.com
    ftp://www.foo.co.uk?bar
    ftp://www.foo.co.uk:8080/bar
);

for(@test){
    print "url: $_\n";

    /^
    (?:\w+:\/\/)?
    [^:?#\/\s]*?

    (
    [^.\s]+
    \.(?:[a-z]{2,}|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|org\.au|com\.au|___etc___)
    )

    (?:[:?#\/]|$)
    /xi;

    print "matched: $1\n";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to double escape the first \w in the beginning of the string, should be "\\w". If you see any other single backslashes escape them.

Comment: I've searched on google for about an hour, and find your answer suits my situation best. Thanks. But there's seems a little problem in java regex String, it should be like this "^(?:\\w+://)?[^:?#/\\s]*?([^.\\s]+\\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|co\\.uk|org\\.uk|ac\\.uk|org\\.au|com\\.au|com.cn|___etc___))(?:[:?#/].*|$)"

Answer (score 4):

`new URL(url).getHost()`

No regex needed.

Comment: Good, but won't work inside a high throughput loop :)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to get a list of all possible TLDs and ccTLDs and then match against them.  You have to do this else you'll never be able to distinguish between subdomain.dom.com and hello.co.uk.

So, get your self such a list.  I recommend inverting it so you store, for example, uk.co.
Then, you can extract the domain from a URL by getting everying between // and / or end of line.  Split at . and work backwards, matching the TLD and then 1 additional level to get the domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /[^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?$/
```

Almost there, but won't match when second-level domain has 3 characters like this: *www.foo.com*
Test it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public static String getDomain(String url){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) return null;
    String domain = null;
    if(url.startsWith("http://")) {
        url = url.replace("http://", "").trim();
    } else if(url.startsWith("https://")) {
        url = url.replace("https://", "").trim();
    }
    String[] temp = url.split("/");
    if(temp != null && temp.length > 0) {
        domain = temp[0];
    }  
    return domain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
public class DomainUrlUtils {
    private static String[] TLD = {"com", "net"}; // top-level domain
    private static String[] SLD = {"co\\.kr"}; // second-level domain

    public static String getDomainName(String url) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=)[^(\\.|\\/)]\\w+\\.(" + joinTldAndSld("|") + ")$");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(url);
        String domain = null;

        if (match.find()) {
            domain = match.group();
        }

        return domain;
    }

    private static String joinTldAndSld(String delimiter) {
        String t = String.join(delimiter, TLD);
        String s = String.join(delimiter, SLD);

        return new StringBuilder(t).append(s.isEmpty() ? "" : "|" + s).toString();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class DomainUrlUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void getDomainName() throws Exception {
        // given
        String[][] domainUrls = {
            {
                "test.com",
                "sub1.test.com",
                "sub1.sub2.test.com",
                "https://sub1.test.com",
                "http://sub1.sub2.test.com"
            },
            {
                "https://domain.com",
                "https://sub.domain.com"
            },
            {
                "http://domain.co.kr",
                "http://sub.domain.co.kr",
                "http://local.sub.domain.co.kr",
                "http://local-test.sub.domain.co.kr",
                "sub.domain.co.kr",
                "domain.co.kr",
                "test.sub.domain.co.kr"
            }
        };

        String[] expectedUrls = {
            "test.com",
            "domain.com",
            "domain.co.kr"
        };

        // when
        // then
        for (int domainIndex = 0; domainIndex < domainUrls.length; domainIndex++) {
            for (String url : domainUrls[domainIndex]) {
                String convertedUrl = DomainUrlUtils.getDomainName(url);

                if (expectedUrls[domainIndex].equals(convertedUrl)) {
                    System.out.println(url + " -> " + convertedUrl);
                } else {
                    Assert.fail("origin Url: " + url + " / converted Url: " + convertedUrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
test.com -> test.com
sub1.test.com -> test.com
sub1.sub2.test.com -> test.com
https://sub1.test.com -> test.com
http://sub1.sub2.test.com -> test.com
https://domain.com -> domain.com
https://sub.domain.com -> domain.com
http://domain.co.kr -> domain.co.kr
http://sub.domain.co.kr -> domain.co.kr
http://local.sub.domain.co.kr -> domain.co.kr
http://local-test.sub.domain.co.kr -> domain.co.kr
sub.domain.co.kr -> domain.co.kr
```