# easy way to get the top level domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to get the domain extention (at least i hope it is called this way) from the site name the user is currently on.

so from www.bbc.co.uk it's co.uk and
www.google.com = .com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask = .com

etc.

especially the ones with the double name (like co.uk) gives me headaches....

EDIT
as i understand from the comments, co.uk is not a top level domain? that makes life easier!
EDIT 
new name (top level domain) in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a toplevel domain (tld) but for the BBC that's just "uk", not "co.uk".

What you want does not follow a standard so you'll need a table to check 'potential' pseudo-tld's

Answer (score 2):

The .co.uk is the .co subdomain of the .uk tld.  This question doesn't make sense in terms of the actual structure of dns.

Comment: always thought .co.uk was 'one' and not a subdomain

Comment: There are other subdomains in the .uk like .ac.uk which is similar to .edu.  The '.' is always a separator.

Answer (score 2):

The PublicSuffix project from mozilla is the solution. It is a maintained list of TLD.

You can use the following nuget package [Nager.PublicSuffix](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.PublicSuffix/).

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.PublicSuffix
```

**Example**

```
var domainParser = new DomainParser(new WebTldRuleProvider());

var domainName = domainParser.Get("sub.test.co.uk");
//domainName.Domain = "test";
//domainName.Hostname = "sub.test.co.uk";
//domainName.RegistrableDomain = "test.co.uk";
//domainName.SubDomain = "sub";
//domainName.TLD = "co.uk";
```

Answer (score 1):

See this question

[Regular expression to retrieve domain.tld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863297/regular-expression-to-retrieve-domain-tld)

The .NET URI class can also retrieve the hostname, of course.

Comment: But this does not really answer the question, especially not the co.uk case.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Top Level Domain and then there's the first sub-domain, which not everyone uses. It's because the first DNS did reverse entries on the split list, to route faster, so it would've parsed to

```
uk -> co -> example -> www
```