# Regexp to get domain from URL

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3

Anyone knows the Regexp for AS3 to get the domain name from URL?
E.g: "http://www.google.com/translate" will get "http://www.google.com"

Comment: If you don't care about TLD with double endings (co.uk, co.jp etc) then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863297/regular-expression-to-retrieve-domain-tld or google for "RegExp tld"

Answer (score 7):

There's is a very complete utility class for dealing with URIs in [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/). Perhaps you might want to use this instead of rolling your own.

```
import com.adobe.net.URI;
var uri:URI = new URI("http://www.google.com/translate");
trace(uri.authority); // traces www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work: `http(s?)://([\w]+\.){1}([\w]+\.?)+`
You can try this in GSkinner [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
.*\/\/([^\/:]+).*
```

Surrounds the regexp by the preferred separators, which might depend on language.
[This diagram](https://regexper.com/#.*%5C%2F%5C%2F%28%5B%5E%5C%2F%3A%5D%2B%29.*) explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The previous regex provided missed some url types i needed, so for the benefit of googlers, I use

(http://|https://)?(www.)?[A-z]*(.com|.co.uk|.us|.org|.net|.mobi)

in C#

```
var regexMatch = Regex.Match(input, @"(http://|https://)?(www.)?[A-z]*(.com|.co.uk|.us|.org|.net|.mobi)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

string domain = regexMatch.Value;
```

See example at [RegExr](http://regexr.com?34uud).

You can remove remove "(...)?" parts to stop that part appearing the match, for example to remove the http matching that I require.

Probably not perfect, but works for me. [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is an excellent reference for building up expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to get the domain from the window.location.href property is provided below. Modifications have to made to a regex answer provided previously by OXMO456 to make it correct and accommodate more scenarios.

```
domainRegex = /(http(?:s?):\/\/(?:[\w]+(?:\.|\:)){1}(?:[\w]+\.?)+)/gi;
```

Regexr link: https://regexr.com/4vnnc