# How to get the domain 'name' of a url in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

How to get the domain 'name' of a url? For example, 
http://www.example.com
http://example.com

To always get 'example' part.

Should I use Regex? How should I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431523/regexp-to-get-domain-from-url

Comment: What programming language are you using? Most have libraries to do the sort of thing you're after e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx