# Get domain name from given url

Tags: java, url

Given a URL, I want to extract domain name(It should not include 'www' part). Url can contain http/https. Here is the java code that I wrote. Though It seems to work fine, is there any better approach or are there some edge cases, that could fail.

```
public static String getDomainName(String url) throws MalformedURLException{
    if(!url.startsWith("http") && !url.startsWith("https")){
         url = "http://" + url;
    }        
    URL netUrl = new URL(url);
    String host = netUrl.getHost();
    if(host.startsWith("www")){
        host = host.substring("www".length()+1);
    }
    return host;
}
```

Input: http://google.com/blah

Output: google.com

Comment: Try `http://74.125.226.70` and let me know how that works out :)

Comment: It just returns IP address. 74.125.226.70

Comment: And how would you get the _domain name_ from that? Assuming that's what you're after..

Comment: For example `http://www.de/` or `http://www.com/` will not give the desired results.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

If you want to parse a URL, use [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).  `java.net.URL` has a bunch of problems -- its `equals` method does a DNS lookup which means code using it can be vulnerable to denial of service attacks when used with untrusted inputs.

["Mr. Gosling -- why did you make url equals suck?"](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2006/12/05/mr-gosling-why-did-you-make-url-equals-suck/) explains one such problem.  Just get in the habit of using `java.net.URI` instead.

```
public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```

should do what you want.

---

> Though It seems to work fine, is there any better approach or are there some edge cases, that could fail.

Your code as written fails for the valid URLs:

- `httpfoo/bar` -- relative URL with a path component that starts with `http`.
- `HTTP://example.com/` -- protocol is case-insensitive.
- `//example.com/` -- protocol relative URL with a host
- `www/foo` -- a relative URL with a path component that starts with `www`
- `wwwexample.com` -- domain name that does not starts with `www.` but starts with `www`.

Hierarchical URLs have a complex grammar.  If you try to roll your own parser without carefully reading RFC 3986, you will probably get it wrong.  Just use the one that's built into the core libraries.

If you really need to deal with messy inputs that `java.net.URI` rejects, see [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) Appendix B:

> #### Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression
>
> As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is identical to the "greedy"
>      disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it is
>      natural and commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing the
>      potential five components of a URI reference.
>
> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
>      well-formed URI reference into its components.
>
> ```
>   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line above are only to assist readability;
>      they indicate the reference points for each subexpression (i.e., each
>      paired parenthesis).

Comment: @Jitendra, I recommend you don't work on fixing them.  The Java libraries people have already done the work for you.

Comment: Also for URI netUrl = new URI("www.google.com");  netUrl.getHost() returns NULL. I think I still need to check for http:// or https://

Comment: @Jitendra, `www.google.com` is a relative URL with a path component that is `www.google.com`.  For example, if resolved against `http://example.com/`, you would get `http://example.com/www.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks Mike,. If I understood correct, with library, you mean, either use URI or regex above?

Comment: @Jitendra, yes.  That is what I recommend.  Parsing dense formats like URLs are tricky.  I would only roll my own parser if I have a compelling need and a few days to read the relevant specifications, collect testcases, implement and test.

Comment: URI host will be null if it contains special characters, for example: "öob.se"

Comment: if domain name contians underscode ( _ ) then uri.getHost(); is returning null.

Answer (score 115):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseURL {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                       + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

    System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol()); //http
    System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority()); //example.com:80
    System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost()); //example.com
    System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort()); //80
    System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath()); //  /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
    System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery()); //name=networking
    System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile()); ///docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
    System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef()); //DOWNLOADING
  }
}
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)

Comment: Thanks! We can use Java `URL` class instead of Android `Uri` for unit-testing. Now I see a difference between `authority` and `host`.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a short and simple line using `InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain()` in Guava: `InternetDomainName.from(new URL(url).getHost()).topPrivateDomain().toString()`

Given `http://www.google.com/blah`, that will give you `google.com`. Or, given `http://www.google.co.mx`, it will give you `google.co.mx`.

As [Sa Qada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1808829/sa-qada) commented in [another answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466564/266531), this question has been asked earlier: [Extract main domain name from a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217271/extract-main-domain-name-from-a-given-url/). The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125823/266531) to that question is from [Satya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3071465/satya), who suggests Guava's [InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html)

> public boolean isTopPrivateDomain()
>
> Indicates whether this domain name is composed of exactly one
>   subdomain component followed by a public suffix. For example, returns
>   true for google.com and foo.co.uk, but not for www.google.com or
>   co.uk.
>
> Warning: A true result from this method does not imply that the
>   domain is at the highest level which is addressable as a host, as many
>   public suffixes are also addressable hosts. For example, the domain
>   bar.uk.com has a public suffix of uk.com, so it would return true from
>   this method. But uk.com is itself an addressable host.
>
> This method can be used to determine whether a domain is probably the
>   highest level for which cookies may be set, though even that depends
>   on individual browsers' implementations of cookie controls. See RFC
>   2109 for details.

Putting that together with `URL.getHost()`, which the original post already contains, gives you:

```
import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName;

import java.net.URL;

public class DomainNameMain {

  public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
    final String urlString = "http://www.google.com/blah";
    final URL url = new URL(urlString);
    final String host = url.getHost();
    final InternetDomainName name = InternetDomainName.from(host).topPrivateDomain();
    System.out.println(urlString);
    System.out.println(host);
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: no preview on this?

Comment: @gumuruh, do you mean a Javascript snippet? This is Java.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a method (see below) which extracts a url's domain name and which uses simple String matching. What it actually does is extract the bit between the first `"://"` (or index `0` if there's no `"://"` contained) and the first subsequent `"/"` (or index `String.length()` if there's no subsequent `"/"`). The remaining, preceding `"www(_)*."` bit is chopped off. I'm sure there will be cases where this is not good enough but it should be good enough for most cases.

[Mike Samuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608008/1071320) says that the [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class can do this and is preferred to the [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class but I encountered problems with the [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class. Notably, the [java.net.URI.getHost()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getHost--) method returns a null value if the url does not include the scheme, i.e. the `"http(s)"` bit.

```
/**
 * Extracts the domain name from {@code url}
 * by means of String manipulation
 * rather than using the {@link URI} or {@link URL} class.
 *
 * @param url is non-null.
 * @return the domain name within {@code url}.
 */
public String getUrlDomainName(String url) {
  String domainName = new String(url);

  int index = domainName.indexOf("://");

  if (index != -1) {
    // keep everything after the "://"
    domainName = domainName.substring(index + 3);
  }

  index = domainName.indexOf('/');

  if (index != -1) {
    // keep everything before the '/'
    domainName = domainName.substring(0, index);
  }

  // check for and remove a preceding 'www'
  // followed by any sequence of characters (non-greedy)
  // followed by a '.'
  // from the beginning of the string
  domainName = domainName.replaceFirst("^www.*?\\.", "");

  return domainName;
}
```

Comment: I think this might not be correct for `http://bob.com:8080/service/read?name=robert`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Lee. Note that I did qualify my answer with "I'm sure there'll be cases where this won't be good enough...". My answer will need some slight modifying for your particular case.

Answer (score 4):

In my case i only needed the main domain and not the subdomain (no "www" or whatever the subdomain is) :

```
public static String getUrlDomain(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    String[] domainArray = domain.split("\\.");
    if (domainArray.length == 1) {
        return domainArray[0];
    }
    return domainArray[domainArray.length - 2] + "." + domainArray[domainArray.length - 1];
}
```

With this method the url "https://rest.webtoapp.io/llSlider?lg=en&t=8" will have for domain "webtoapp.io".

Answer (score 4):

All the above are good. This one seems really simple to me and easy to understand. Excuse the quotes. I wrote it for Groovy inside a class called DataCenter.

```
static String extractDomainName(String url) {
    int start = url.indexOf('://')
    if (start < 0) {
        start = 0
    } else {
        start += 3
    }
    int end = url.indexOf('/', start)
    if (end < 0) {
        end = url.length()
    }
    String domainName = url.substring(start, end)

    int port = domainName.indexOf(':')
    if (port >= 0) {
        domainName = domainName.substring(0, port)
    }
    domainName
}
```

And here are some junit4 tests:

```
@Test
void shouldFindDomainName() {
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('http://example.com/path/') == 'example.com'
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('http://subpart.example.com/path/') == 'subpart.example.com'
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('http://example.com') == 'example.com'
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('http://example.com:18445/path/') == 'example.com'
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('example.com/path/') == 'example.com'
    assert DataCenter.extractDomainName('example.com') == 'example.com'
}
```

Comment: great thanks for simpllicity! :D

Answer (score 3):

I made a small treatment after the URI object creation

```
 if (url.startsWith("http:/")) {
        if (!url.contains("http://")) {
            url = url.replaceAll("http:/", "http://");
        }
    } else {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
```

Answer (score 3):

`val host = url.split("/")[2]`

Answer (score 1):

try this one : java.net.URL;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getDomainName(new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains")));

```
public String getDomainName(URL url){
String strDomain;
String[] strhost = url.getHost().split(Pattern.quote("."));
String[] strTLD = {"com","org","net","int","edu","gov","mil","arpa"};

if(Arrays.asList(strTLD).indexOf(strhost[strhost.length-1])>=0)
    strDomain = strhost[strhost.length-2]+"."+strhost[strhost.length-1];
else if(strhost.length>2)
    strDomain = strhost[strhost.length-3]+"."+strhost[strhost.length-2]+"."+strhost[strhost.length-1];
else
    strDomain = strhost[strhost.length-2]+"."+strhost[strhost.length-1];
return strDomain;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [Extract main domain name from a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217271/extract-main-domain-name-from-a-given-url/).  If you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466483/1808829) , you will see that it is very easy. You just need to use `java.net.URL` and `String` utility - `Split`

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String hostExtractorRegexString = "(?:https?://)?(?:www\\.)?(.+\\.)(com|au\\.uk|co\\.in|be|in|uk|org\\.in|org|net|edu|gov|mil)";
private static final Pattern hostExtractorRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(hostExtractorRegexString);

public static String getDomainName(String url){
    if (url == null) return null;
    url = url.trim();
    Matcher m = hostExtractorRegexPattern.matcher(url);
    if(m.find() && m.groupCount() == 2) {
        return m.group(1) + m.group(2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Explanation :**
The regex has 4 groups. The first two are non-matching groups and the next two are matching groups.

The first non-matching group is "http" or "https" or ""

The second non-matching group is "www." or ""

The second matching group is the [top level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain)

The first matching group is anything after the non-matching groups and anything before the top level domain

The concatenation of the two matching groups will give us the domain/host name.

PS : Note that you can add any number of supported domains to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way I did and worked for all of the cases is using Guava Library and regex in combination.

```
public static String getDomainNameWithGuava(String url) throws MalformedURLException, 
  URISyntaxException {
    String host =new URL(url).getHost();
    String domainName="";
    try{
        domainName = InternetDomainName.from(host).topPrivateDomain().toString();
    }catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException e){
        domainName= getDomain(url,true);
    }
    return domainName;
}
```

getDomain() can be any common method with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the input url is user input. this method gives the most appropriate host name. if not found gives back the input url.

```
private String getHostName(String urlInput) {
        urlInput = urlInput.toLowerCase();
        String hostName=urlInput;
        if(!urlInput.equals("")){
            if(urlInput.startsWith("http") || urlInput.startsWith("https")){
                try{
                    URL netUrl = new URL(urlInput);
                    String host= netUrl.getHost();
                    if(host.startsWith("www")){
                        hostName = host.substring("www".length()+1);
                    }else{
                        hostName=host;
                    }
                }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    hostName=urlInput;
                }
            }else if(urlInput.startsWith("www")){
                hostName=urlInput.substring("www".length()+1);
            }
            return  hostName;
        }else{
            return  "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual domain name, without the subdomain, I use:

```
private String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    String hostName = new URI(url).getHost();
    if (!hostName.contains(".")) {
        return hostName;
    }
    String[] host = hostName.split("\\.");
    return host[host.length - 2];
}
```

Note that this won't work with second-level domains (like .co.uk).

Answer (score 0):

```
// groovy
String hostname ={url -> url[(url.indexOf('://')+ 3)..-1]​.split('/')[0]​ }

hostname('http://hello.world.com/something') // return 'hello.world.com'
hostname('docker://quay.io/skopeo/stable') // return 'quay.io'
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
const val WWW = "www."

fun URL.domain(): String {
    val domain: String = this.host
    return if (domain.startsWith(ConstUtils.WWW)) {
        domain.substring(ConstUtils.WWW.length)
    } else {
        domain
    }
}
```