# Most elegant way to get domain name without www in jsp

Tags: jsp, google-analytics

I am currently sending the domain name to GA using:

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '${esapi:encodeForJavaScript(request.serverName)}']);`

This outputs: `www.somedomain.com`

What is the most elegant solution in jsp to remove the `www.`, leaving just `somedomain.com`?

Comment: Duplicate: [Get domain name from given url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url).

Comment: I've voted to close, I believe my question is a duplicate

Comment: Mostly, yes, regarding extraction of value in a servlet, that's why I made the initial comment. Still, your question is **not a duplicate** in respect to how to do it using JSTL/EL. Check out my answer to find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the request implements `HttpServletRequest` you can access the URI directly by calling `request.getRequestURI()` to use in in conjunction with [Get domain name from given url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608008/1820286) answer.

Also, be sure to check out javadocs on [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to find out other interesting methods like, for example, `getServerName`.

---

As to the problem of how you can get what you need in JSP, not in servlet/scriptlet, you'd need to use JSTL `fn:replace` function like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

${fn:replace(request.serverName, 'www.','')}
```

Comment: Be aware of reverse proxies like Nginx. Usually they don't touch the Server Name but they most definitely will change the originating IP and the protocol. You will have to get around this with special `X-headers`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
```

Comment: By the way, `url` doesn't have public visibility. Moreover, in fact, there is no `url` proberty. The method you referred to is `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL`.

Comment: Thanks skuntsel. I had intution of it but was not sure. Just wanted to give OP a headsup. Reverting back to url