# Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables

Tags: android, uri, uribuilder

I'm developing an Android app. I need to build a URI for my app to make an API request. Unless there's another way to put a variable in a URI, this is the easiest way I've found. I found that you need to use `Uri.Builder`, but I'm not quite sure how to. My url is:

```
http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=[redacted]&mapid=value
```

My scheme is http, authority is `lapi.transitchicago.com`, path is `/api/1.0`, path segment(s) is `ttarrivals.aspx`, and query string is `key=[redacted]&mapid=value`.

My code is below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getExtras().getString("value");
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
    .authority("www.lapi.transitchicago.com")
    .appendPath("api")
    .appendPath("1.0")
    .appendPath("ttarrivals.aspx")
    .appendQueryParameter("key", "[redacted]")
    .appendQueryParameter("mapid", value);
```

I understand that I can do `URI.add`, but how do I integrate it into the `Uri.Builder`? Should I add everything like `URI.add(scheme)`, `URI.add(authority)` and so on? Or is that not the way to do it? Also, is there any other easier way to add a variable to a URI/URL?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059289/2914140 for Java `URL` class. It can be used in unit-testing.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

Let's say that I want to create the following URL:

```
https://www.myawesomesite.com/turtles/types?type=1&sort=relevance#section-name
```

To build this with the [`Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) I would do the following.

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("www.myawesomesite.com")
    .appendPath("turtles")
    .appendPath("types")
    .appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
    .appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
    .fragment("section-name");
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: With my path segment, would it be a path? Or would it be a query?

Comment: If it is a path, then it would be `appendPath()` for the method. If it is a query string (coming after the ?) then use `appendQueryParameter()`. Take a look at the URL that I have in the example and what I am doing with each segment. I also added `toString()` to the `build()` call to get the proper type back.

Comment: It's before the question mark, but it doesn't have a / after it. It's ttarrivals.aspx on my question above. So that would be a path?

Comment: Correct. It just happens to be the end of the path. Technically you could put a "/" at the end if you wanted and it would be valid.

http://www.mysite.com/path is the same as http://www.mysite.com/path/

Comment: I think that for the "types", you need to use 'appendEncodedPath'

Comment: Perfect answer! This should have been in the API documentation already.

Comment: Why a URLBuilder instead of just providing a constructor? Is that to enforce immutability?

Comment: +1 for explaining url having #... Is there any documentation where we can say that ok, If # then use fragment..if &, then, appendQueryparameter and so on...

Comment: So much easier in Java with URI.  Android makes 10 steps to create something so simple in Java.  URI.create("https://www.myawesomesite.com/turtles/types?type=1&sort=relevance#section-name"

Answer (score 361):

There is another way of using `Uri` and we can achieve the same goal

```
http://api.example.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7
```

To build the Uri you can use this:

```
final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = 
    "http://api.example.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
```

You can declare all this the above way or even inside the `Uri.parse()` and `appendQueryParameter()`

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL)
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, "json")
    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, "metric")
    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(7))
    .build();
```

At last

```
URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
```

- Source: [Udacity Android course / Sunshine app](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/2.07_build_url_with_params/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/ForecastFragment.java#L141)

Comment: You deserve more votes! For me, the basic use case is when you have an already defined string URL, and you want to add/append parameters!

Comment: I was looking for a solution for sunshine (this exact string) but the most voted question provides much more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks for the Uri.buildUpon() hint! Saved me some headaches.

Comment: I was confused in what order url are made, because in course its only variables not the complete url, that we have to make

Comment: What if I don't have the base url but the complete url instead? Using Parse+BuildUpon+AppendQueryParam+Build I get a non valid url ([domain][queryParams][path] instead of [domain][path][queryParams])

Answer (score 24):

Excellent answer from above turned into a simple utility method.

```
private Uri buildURI(String url, Map<String, String> params) {

    // build url with parameters.
    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: No need convert UTF8 content?

Answer (score 22):

here is a good way to explain it:

there are two forms of the URI

1 - Builder(ready to be **modified**, **not** ready to be **used**)

2 - Built(**not** ready to be **modified**, ready to be **used** )

You can create a builder by

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
```

this gonna return a **Builder** ready to be modified like this:-

```
builder.scheme("https");
builder.authority("api.github.com");
builder.appendPath("search");
builder.appendPath("repositories");
builder.appendQueryParameter(PARAMETER_QUERY,parameterValue);
```

but to use it you have to build it first

```
retrun builder.build();
```

or however you gonna use it.
and then you have **built** that is already built for you, ready to use but cannot be modified.

```
Uri built = Uri.parse("your URI goes here");
```

this is ready to use but if you want to modify it you need to **buildUpon()**

```
Uri built = Uri.parse("Your URI goes here")
           .buildUpon(); //now it's ready to be modified
           .buildUpon()
           .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAMATER, parameterValue) 
           //any modification you want to make goes here
           .build(); // you have to build it back cause you are storing it 
                     // as Uri not Uri.builder
```

now every time you want to modify it you need to **buildUpon()** and in the end **build()**.

so **Uri.Builder** is a **Builder** type that store a Builder in it.
**Uri** is a **Built** type that store an already built URI in it.

**new Uri.Builder();** rerurns a **Builder**.
**Uri.parse("your URI goes here")** returns a **Built**.

and with **build()** you can change it from **Builder** to **Built**.
**buildUpon()** you can change it from **Built** to **Builder**.
Here is what you can do

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("URL").buildUpon();
// here you created a builder, made an already built URI with Uri.parse
// and then change it to builder with buildUpon();
Uri built = builder.build();
//when you want to change your URI, change Builder 
//when you want to use your URI, use Built
```

and also the opposite:-

```
Uri built = new Uri.Builder().build();
// here you created a reference to a built URI
// made a builder with new Uri.Builder() and then change it to a built with 
// built();
Uri.Builder builder = built.buildUpon();
```

hope my answer helped :) <3

Answer (score 9):

for the example in the `second` `Answer` I used this technique for the same URL

`http://api.example.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7`

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("https")
                    .authority("api.openweathermap.org")
                    .appendPath("data")
                    .appendPath("2.5")
                    .appendPath("forecast")
                    .appendPath("daily")
                    .appendQueryParameter("q", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("mode", "json")
                    .appendQueryParameter("units", "metric")
                    .appendQueryParameter("cnt", "7")
                    .appendQueryParameter("APPID", BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY);
```

then after finish building it get it as `URL` like this

```
URL url = new URL(builder.build().toString());
```

and open a connection

```
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

and if link is `simple` like location uri, for example

`geo:0,0?q=29203`

```
Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("q",29203).build();
```

Comment: `URL url = new URL(builder.build().toString());` has to wrapped by a try catch block for MalformedURLException

Answer (score 4):

Using `appendEncodePath()` could save you multiple lines than `appendPath()`, the following code snippet builds up this url: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=94043`

```
Uri.Builder urlBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
urlBuilder.scheme("http");
urlBuilder.authority("api.openweathermap.org");
urlBuilder.appendEncodedPath("data/2.5/forecast/daily");
urlBuilder.appendQueryParameter("zip", "94043,us");
URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.build().toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168199/413127

Example for

```
 http://api.example.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7
```

Now with Kotlin

```
 val myUrl = Uri.Builder().apply {
        scheme("https")
        authority("www.myawesomesite.com")
        appendPath("turtles")
        appendPath("types")
        appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
        appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
        fragment("section-name")
        build()            
    }.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the Kotlin version :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with lambda expressions;

```
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.example.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily";

    private String getBaseUrl(Map<String, String> params) {
        final Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon();
        params.entrySet().forEach(entry -> builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        return builder.build().toString();
    }
```

and you can create params like that;

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("zip", "94043,us");
    params.put("units", "metric");
```

**Btw.** If you will face any issue like `“lambda expressions not supported at this language level”`, please check this URL;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704620/2057154

Comment: And what to do after setting params?

Comment: Params is the parameter of the ’getBaseUrl’ method. For calling this method you need to pass params.

Comment: thank you! It would be better if you show a resulting URL (I used another solution).