# Android Uri.Builder unable to resolve host

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am trying get from this address:

server-staging.co/api/v1

using OKHttp lib. After running the following code:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
       .authority("server-staging.co/api/v1");

requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(new URL(builder.build().toString()));

Request request = requestBuilder.build();
Response response = mOkHttpClient.newCall(request)
                                         .execute();
```

I receive the following warning, which I've been unable to resolve.

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "server-staging.co%2Fapi%2Fv1": No address associated with
>   hostname

Answer (score 0):

Do not add "api/v1" directly to the String, it is most like a parse URI
You might add these paths as in this answer [URI appendPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables)