# Best Practice to build URL in android

Tags: android, url, uri

What is the best practice to build Http Uri in Android. I want to use Uri.Builder to build the url.

I want to create a class which will return all the Http urls including parameters.

I checked the below link for Uri.Builder which gives idea to utilise in case of get request but how to use the power of Uri.Builder in post request too.

[Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables)

Over all I am asking for best practice to build Http Urls(Get and post both ) by utilising power of Uri.Builder

Comment: Any reason for downvote

Comment: See [use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables) for a great set of answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not differences between a GET and a POST url. The http request method will be different but URI can be the same.

For example check this [one](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/settings) and this [one](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/settings). Both of them use the same resource Url but differents methods.

Uri.Builder is made to create Uri, you can use it for both GET and POST. So to build the Uri `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json` (from the example above) I can use this code

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("api.twitter.com")
    .appendPath("1.1")
    .appendPath("account")
    .appendPath("settings.json");
Uri uri = builder.build();
```

I think you are searching for something like a HttpRequest.Builder but I don't know one. You can still use a third party library like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: Thanks I am going to use retorfit