# URI builder in Android, odd URL

Tags: android, uri, uribuilder

I'm trying to use the URI builder in Android to create a URL with variables. I have read [Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables), but some symbols that I need aren't covered in that.

An example of URL that I want to create:

"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories|coordinates|pageprops&format=json&clshow=!hidden&coprop=type%7Cname%7Cdim%7Ccountry%7Cregion%7Cglobe&codistancefrompoint=38.11386944444445%7C13.356263888888888&generator=geosearch&redirects=&ggscoord=38.11386944444445%7C13.356263888888888&ggsradius=100&ggslimit=10&ggsnamespace=6&ggsprop=type%7Cname%7Cdim%7Ccountry%7Cregion%7Cglobe&ggsprimary=all&formatversion=2"

I will want to substitute the ggscoord with a variable. I know how to append the path and query parameters... but what builder method should I use for the %7C and | ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to modify query, you may use appendQueryParameter for plain strings like "|", any you may use encodedQuery for pre-encoded strings like "%7C".

There is no append method for pre-encoded query parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Character like `%7C` has been encoded,maybe it's a Chinese code or others,so if you want to add some parameters to your URL,just use [URLEncoder.encode](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to encode your primitive string.
like this:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
.authority("www.lapi.transitchicago.com")
.appendPath("api")
.appendPath("1.0")
.appendPath("ttarrivals.aspx")
.appendQueryParameter("key", "[redacted]")
.appendQueryParameter("mapid",URLEncoder.encode("&&&","UTF-8"); //note this
```