# Android Uri.Builder using "/" instead of "//" after scheme

Tags: android, uri, uribuilder

I dug through the source code, but I just can't find a reason for this behavior.

According to [Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables), this should work absolutely fine.

Say I want to connect to `https://www.gravatar.com/eac16c9fc481cb6825f8b3a35f916b5c.json`

Then, I have this code to print three separate ways of getting that address.

```
String userHash = "eac16c9fc481cb6825f8b3a35f916b5c";

String correctUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/" + userHash + ".json";
Uri.Builder builder1 = Uri.parse(correctUrl).buildUpon();

Uri.Builder builder2 = new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("https")
        .path("www.gravatar.com")
        .appendPath(userHash + ".json");

Log.i("Correct URL", correctUrl);
Log.i("Builder 1 URL", builder1.toString());
Log.i("Builder 2 URL", builder2.toString());
```

The first two print fine, but that third one is what I would prefer to use, but it isn't correct as you can see `http:/www` instead of `http://www`

```
I/Correct URL:   https://www.gravatar.com/eac16c9fc481cb6825f8b3a35f916b5c.json
I/Builder 1 URL: https://www.gravatar.com/eac16c9fc481cb6825f8b3a35f916b5c.json
I/Builder 2 URL: https:/www.gravatar.com/eac16c9fc481cb6825f8b3a35f916b5c.json
```

I am compiling with API 23, and I haven't bothered to try a different API version because I am just confused why this wouldn't work.

Comment: You need to set the URL path to the `authority()`, instead to the `path` which will always give you 1 forward slash. remove `.path("www.gravatar.com")` add `authority("www.gravatar.com")`, [Here for more info][1]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Ohh, I see that now in the other post :) Oops. Thank you. Feel free to answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the URL path to the `authority()`, instead to the `path` which will always give you 1 forward slash. remove `.path("www.gravatar.com")` add `authority("www.gravatar.com")`,

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) is more info why authority is used.

Comment: I suppose I could have also read about URI's on Wikipedia and seen the authority follows the scheme. Thanks again.