# Uri-Difference between appendPath() and appendQueryParameter()

Tags: android

I am developing a Weather app ,in that trying to build Uri that looks like
Content://com.example.weather.app/Location/locationName?Date=12012017

The documentation says Uri reference has pattern as ://?#

trying to understand this following code

```
 public static Uri buildWeatherLocation(String locationSetting) {
                    return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(locationSetting).build();
                }

                public static Uri buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
                        String locationSetting, long startDate) {
                    long normalizedDate = normalizeDate(startDate);
                    return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(locationSetting)
                         .appendQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE,Long.toString(normalizedDate)).build();     

                }
```

what is the actual difference and when we use `appendPath()` and `appendQueryParameter()` methods?
why can't we use `appendQueryParameter()` for locationSetting ,bit confusing suggestions plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendPath()` is for path segments and `appendQueryParameter()` for query params with key value (in your example **Date**=**12012017**).

Check this link for more info and examples:
[Use URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables)

Answer (score 0):

appendQueryParameter is for query string parameters and appendPath is for site path

Comment: can   .appendPath(locationSetting) be used as .appendQueryParameter(LOCATIONNAME,locationSetting) so that it becomes part of <query>