# How is it possible to use abstract Uri buildUpon() method?

Tags: java, android

Uri buildUpon() is declared as abstract so how can we use it in a statement like this as its not implemented in Uri class.

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_QUERY, githubSearchQuery)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_SORT, sortBy)
                .build();
```

Comment: `parse(url)` is not abstract and returns a concrete instance. `buildUpon()` is invoked on this instance.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables) for buildUpon() in URI.

Comment: parse returns a Uri, but how can we call buildUpon on it.. thats my confusion