# Trying to do a get request with url built with URI builder

Tags: java, android, uri

I am using a uri builder for a news app. I've checked similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing I tried seems to be working. Here is my code :

```
 Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
     .scheme("https")
    .authority("content.guardianapis.com")
    .appendPath("search")
    .appendQueryParameter("tags", "contributor")
    .appendQueryParameter("key", "dac25c9f-6360-4f05-b81d-689063b0a931");
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: share the error you getting

Comment: I think this topic will help:
[URI builder in Android or create URL with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables)

Comment: there is not error but this is the url I wanna build :https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=dac25c9f-6360-4f05-b81d-689063b0a931&show-tags=contributor

Comment: @nicek I wrote the code above based on the content in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the order of my request params were wrong