# How to get domain of example.co.ir in java

Tags: java, url

I need to parse url in my java code and get the domain. I wrote the following code:

```
    static String domain(URL url) {
        String host = url.getHost();
        int i = host.lastIndexOf('.');
                if(i == -1){

                    return "Not domain";
                }
                if (i ==0 ){

                    return "Not domain";
                }
                String domain; 
                i = host.lastIndexOf('.', i - 1);
                if (i == -1) {
                    domain = host;
                }
                else {
                    domain = host.substring(i + 1, host.length());
                }
    }
```

This code parses domains like **example.com**

But how can my code parse domains like **exmaple.co.ir** , **subdomains.example.co.ir** and the others extensions like **co.uk**, **org.ir** and so on.

**EDIT**

my url is **http//blog.example.co.ir/index.php** or **http//blog.example.co.uk/something.html**

my goal is to print:

**example.co.ir** and **example.co.uk**

Comment: I am confused by your question.  getHost() should return the host - what am I missing?

Comment: Refer to this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9608008/500725)**

Comment: @user2310289 My code gets a url (http://a.b.c.example.co.ir/index/news/....) then parses it to "a.b.c.example.co.ir"! Finally, it sends out the domain "example.co.ir"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this work for any kind of URL(in correct URL format)

```
domain= host.split("/")[2];
```

**Note:**

`split("/")` will create an array from the String, for example:

```
String host="http//blog.example.co.ir/index.php";
```

`host.split("/")` will give you array of String: `[http, ,blog.example.co.ir, index.php]`

And your desired output is at index `2`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your parsing code is limited to domains with just one dot. You can use regular expressions or recursive parsing to solve this problem. [This](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/core-java-tutorial/extract-domain-name-using-java-regular-expression) is one way of approaching this problem.