# Get domain name from URL in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, url, domain-name

In my app, I need to get the favicon.ico from a URL. (eg. "http://google.com/favicon.ico").
Users can input all kinds of URLs, and I need only the domain name.

Examples:

```
http://drive.google.com/bla/bla/bla -> drive.google.com

www.facebook.com/lol -> www.facebook.com

192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.1 (but not really necessary)
```

Does anyone have a method to get this?
Thanks!

Comment: can't you wrap it in a Url object and use the getHost() method?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try using something like

```
String u = "www.facebook.com/lol";
URL url = new URL(u);
String host = url.getHost(); // should be www.facebook.com
```

If you need different parts of the Url look at the documentation and the other getters here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html

Comment: From where should I import Url?

Comment: look at doc ;)  java.net.URL

Comment: This will give you malformed exception. Soln : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40405173/1137624

Comment: @cegprakash not if you catch it. Your proposed solution won't match many valid top level domains.

Comment: @cegprakash Where does this statistic come from? Why would a regular expression be the only feasible solution, if you do not catch the majority of TLDs?

Comment: I tried some thousands of URLs. I can catch any TLD just by updating my regex.

Comment: "Won't match man y valid top level domains..."
Can someone please explain this or give an example? What domain name won't work with the code in this answer? And where does the 50% number come from for malformed URL's?