# Java regex to extract domain name?

Tags: java, regex

I need java regex to extract only domain name from a string.

Ex:

```
input : www.google.com  (ouput) --> google.com
    input : https://www.google.com (output) --> google.com
```

Basically it should remove all www and http(s) from URL.
Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use regex for this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Post your attempted regex(es) in your question.

Comment: There is `URL` class in Java for this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 1):

If you interested it doing in regex, try something like this :

```
urlString.replaceFirst("^(https?://)?(www\\.)?", "")
```

However that won't be good idea as comments are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?\.(.*?\.[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/33

Comment: it finds and matches a string like this: "weionheotiwot.w0ioghw0ogiwjgt.wghwoigh"

Answer (score -1):

to achieve this, you need 2 java classes: Matcher and Pattern.

you have to build up the Pattern object and call on it the method which gives you the matcher instance.

```
// in the beginning, import necessary classes
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // this is the array with urls to check
      String [] urls = {"https://google.com", "www.google.com"};

      // now, let's check if strings are matching
      for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {  

          // string to be scanned to find the pattern
          String url = urls[i];
          String pattern = "google.com";

          // create a Pattern object
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          // now, create Matcher object.
          Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

          // let's check if something was found
          if (m.find()) {

             System.out.println("Found value: " + url);

          } else {

             System.out.println("NO MATCH");

          }

       }

   }

}
```

you can add to the array all the urls you want the pattern to check!

Comment: I think the OP wants a more general solution that also works for other domains than google.com