# in java how to extract exact domain name from url

Tags: java, url, dns, subdomain, tld

I am developing one java application and I want to extract exact domain name from URL using java.

I have domain like:

> **helloword.com**
>
> **developer.mydomain.com**
>
> **developer.ourdomain.co.in**
>
> **wowdomain.co.in**

the output should be like this:

> **helloworld**
>
> **mydomain**
>
> **ourdomain**
>
> **wowdomain**

Comment: That's a requirement, not a question. What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried URL class of java but it does not helping me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get domain name from given url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is extracting host part and then go left from the end while there is a TLD string at the start:

```
public static String extractDomainName(String base_url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI siteURI =
            new URI(base_url);
    base_url = siteURI.getHost();
    base_url = base_url.startsWith("www.") ? base_url.substring(4) : base_url;

    String pattern_exceptDot = "[^.]*";
    String pattern_base = pattern_exceptDot + "\\." + pattern_exceptDot;
    String patternCurrent = pattern_base;

    String base_url_temp = base_url;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + pattern_base + ")$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(base_url);
    if (matcher.find())
        base_url_temp = matcher.group(0);
    boolean shouldLoopTLd = true;
    while (shouldLoopTLd)
        for (String tld : Utility.TLDList()) {
            shouldLoopTLd = false;
            if (base_url_temp.toLowerCase().startsWith(tld.toLowerCase() + ".")) {
                shouldLoopTLd = true;
                patternCurrent = pattern_exceptDot + "\\." + patternCurrent;
                pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + patternCurrent + ")$");
                matcher = pattern.matcher(base_url);
                matcher = matcher.reset();
                if (matcher.find())
                    base_url_temp = matcher.group(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    base_url = base_url_temp;
    return base_url;
}
```

While method **TLDList()** returns a list of main domain types, such as 'IR','COM',...

```
    /**
 * Returnes list of TLD (Top Level Domain, such as 'ir','com')
 *
 * @return
 */
public static List<String> TLDList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"AAA", "AARP", "ABARTH", "ABB", "ABBOTT", "ABBVIE", "ABC", "ABLE", "ABOGADO", "ABUDHABI", "AC", "ACADEMY", "ACCENTURE", "ACCOUNTANT", "ACCOUNTANTS", "ACO", "ACTIVE", "ACTOR", "AD", "ADAC", "ADS", "ADULT", "AE", "AEG", "AERO", "AETNA", "AF", "AFAMILYCOMPANY", "AFL", "AFRICA", "AG", "AGAKHAN", "AGENCY", "AI", "AIG", "AIGO", "AIRBUS", "AIRFORCE", "AIRTEL", "AKDN", "AL", "ALFAROMEO", "ALIBABA", "ALIPAY", "ALLFINANZ", "ALLSTATE", "ALLY", "ALSACE", "ALSTOM", "AM", "AMERICANEXPRESS", "AMERICANFAMILY", "AMEX", "AMFAM", "AMICA", "AMSTERDAM", "ANALYTICS", "ANDROID", "ANQUAN", "ANZ", "AO", "AOL", "APARTMENTS", "APP", "APPLE", "AQ", "AQUARELLE", "AR", "ARAB", "ARAMCO", "ARCHI", "ARMY", "ARPA", "ART", "ARTE", "AS", "ASDA", "ASIA", "ASSOCIATES", "AT", "ATHLETA", "ATTORNEY", "AU", "AUCTION", "AUDI", "AUDIBLE", "AUDIO", "AUSPOST", "AUTHOR", "AUTO", "AUTOS", "AVIANCA", "AW", "AWS", "AX", "AXA", "AZ", "AZURE", "BA", "BABY", "BAIDU", "BANAMEX", "BANANAREPUBLIC", "BAND", "BANK", "BAR", "BARCELONA", "BARCLAYCARD", "BARCLAYS", "BAREFOOT", "BARGAINS", "BASEBALL", "BASKETBALL", "BAUHAUS", "BAYERN", "BB", "BBC", "BBT", "BBVA", "BCG", "BCN", "BD", "BE", "BEATS", "BEAUTY", "BEER", "BENTLEY", "BERLIN", "BEST", "BESTBUY", "BET", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BHARTI", "BI", "BIBLE", "BID", "BIKE", "BING", "BINGO", "BIO", "BIZ", "BJ", "BLACK", "BLACKFRIDAY", "BLANCO", "BLOCKBUSTER", "BLOG", "BLOOMBERG", "BLUE", "BM", "BMS", "BMW", "BN", "BNL", "BNPPARIBAS", "BO", "BOATS", "BOEHRINGER", "BOFA", "BOM", "BOND", "BOO", "BOOK", "BOOKING", "BOSCH", "BOSTIK", "BOSTON", "BOT", "BOUTIQUE", "BOX", "BR", "BRADESCO", "BRIDGESTONE", "BROADWAY", "BROKER", "BROTHER", "BRUSSELS", "BS", "BT", "BUDAPEST", "BUGATTI", "BUILD", "BUILDERS", "BUSINESS", "BUY", "BUZZ", "BV", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "BZH", "CA", "CAB", "CAFE", "CAL", "CALL", "CALVINKLEIN", "CAM", "CAMERA", "CAMP", "CANCERRESEARCH", "CANON", "CAPETOWN", "CAPITAL", "CAPITALONE", "CAR", "CARAVAN", "CARDS", "CARE", "CAREER", "CAREERS", "CARS", "CARTIER", "CASA", "CASE", "CASEIH", "CASH", "CASINO", "CAT", "CATERING", "CATHOLIC", "CBA", "CBN", "CBRE", "CBS", "CC", "CD", "CEB", "CENTER", "CEO", "CERN", "CF", "CFA", "CFD", "CG", "CH", "CHANEL", "CHANNEL", "CHARITY", "CHASE", "CHAT", "CHEAP", "CHINTAI", "CHRISTMAS", "CHROME", "CHRYSLER", "CHURCH", "CI", "CIPRIANI", "CIRCLE", "CISCO", "CITADEL", "CITI", "CITIC", "CITY", "CITYEATS", "CK", "CL", "CLAIMS", "CLEANING", "CLICK", "CLINIC", "CLINIQUE", "CLOTHING", "CLOUD", "CLUB", "CLUBMED", "CM", "CN", "CO", "COACH", "CODES", "COFFEE", "COLLEGE", "COLOGNE", "COM", "COMCAST", "COMMBANK", "COMMUNITY", "COMPANY", "COMPARE", "COMPUTER", "COMSEC", "CONDOS", "CONSTRUCTION", "CONSULTING", "CONTACT", "CONTRACTORS", "COOKING", "COOKINGCHANNEL", "COOL", "COOP", "CORSICA", "COUNTRY", "COUPON", "COUPONS", "COURSES", "CR", "CREDIT", "CREDITCARD", "CREDITUNION", "CRICKET", "CROWN", "CRS", "CRUISE", "CRUISES", "CSC", "CU", "CUISINELLA", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CYMRU", "CYOU", "CZ", "DABUR", "DAD", "DANCE", "DATA", "DATE", "DATING", "DATSUN", "DAY", "DCLK", "DDS", "DE", "DEAL", "DEALER", "DEALS", "DEGREE", "DELIVERY", "DELL", "DELOITTE", "DELTA", "DEMOCRAT", "DENTAL", "DENTIST", "DESI", "DESIGN", "DEV", "DHL", "DIAMONDS", "DIET", "DIGITAL", "DIRECT", "DIRECTORY", "DISCOUNT", "DISCOVER", "DISH", "DIY", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DNP", "DO", "DOCS", "DOCTOR", "DODGE", "DOG", "DOHA", "DOMAINS", "DOT", "DOWNLOAD", "DRIVE", "DTV", "DUBAI", "DUCK", "DUNLOP", "DUNS", "DUPONT", "DURBAN", "DVAG", "DVR", "DZ", "EARTH", "EAT", "EC", "ECO", "EDEKA", "EDU", "EDUCATION", "EE", "EG", "EMAIL", "EMERCK", "ENERGY", "ENGINEER", "ENGINEERING", "ENTERPRISES", "EPOST", "EPSON", "EQUIPMENT", "ER", "ERICSSON", "ERNI", "ES", "ESQ", "ESTATE", "ESURANCE", "ET", "ETISALAT", "EU", "EUROVISION", "EUS", "EVENTS", "EVERBANK", "EXCHANGE", "EXPERT", "EXPOSED", "EXPRESS", "EXTRASPACE", "FAGE", "FAIL", "FAIRWINDS", "FAITH", "FAMILY", "FAN", "FANS", "FARM", "FARMERS", "FASHION", "FAST", "FEDEX", "FEEDBACK", "FERRARI", "FERRERO", "FI", "FIAT", "FIDELITY", "FIDO", "FILM", "FINAL", "FINANCE", "FINANCIAL", "FIRE", "FIRESTONE", "FIRMDALE", "FISH", "FISHING", "FIT", "FITNESS", "FJ", "FK", "FLICKR", "FLIGHTS", "FLIR", "FLORIST", "FLOWERS", "FLY", "FM", "FO", "FOO", "FOOD", "FOODNETWORK", "FOOTBALL", "FORD", "FOREX", "FORSALE", "FORUM", "FOUNDATION", "FOX", "FR", "FREE", "FRESENIUS", "FRL", "FROGANS", "FRONTDOOR", "FRONTIER", "FTR", "FUJITSU", "FUJIXEROX", "FUN", "FUND", "FURNITURE", "FUTBOL", "FYI", "GA", "GAL", "GALLERY", "GALLO", "GALLUP", "GAME", "GAMES", "GAP", "GARDEN", "GB", "GBIZ", "GD", "GDN", "GE", "GEA", "GENT", "GENTING", "GEORGE", "GF", "GG", "GGEE", "GH", "GI", "GIFT", "GIFTS", "GIVES", "GIVING", "GL", "GLADE", "GLASS", "GLE", "GLOBAL", "GLOBO", "GM", "GMAIL", "GMBH", "GMO", "GMX", "GN", "GODADDY", "GOLD", "GOLDPOINT", "GOLF", "GOO", "GOODHANDS", "GOODYEAR", "GOOG", "GOOGLE", "GOP", "GOT", "GOV", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GRAINGER", "GRAPHICS", "GRATIS", "GREEN", "GRIPE", "GROCERY", "GROUP", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GUARDIAN", "GUCCI", "GUGE", "GUIDE", "GUITARS", "GURU", "GW", "GY", "HAIR", "HAMBURG", "HANGOUT", "HAUS", "HBO", "HDFC", "HDFCBANK", "HEALTH", "HEALTHCARE", "HELP", "HELSINKI", "HERE", "HERMES", "HGTV", "HIPHOP", "HISAMITSU", "HITACHI", "HIV", "HK", "HKT", "HM", "HN", "HOCKEY", "HOLDINGS", "HOLIDAY", "HOMEDEPOT", "HOMEGOODS", "HOMES", "HOMESENSE", "HONDA", "HONEYWELL", "HORSE", "HOSPITAL", "HOST", "HOSTING", "HOT", "HOTELES", "HOTELS", "HOTMAIL", "HOUSE", "HOW", "HR", "HSBC", "HT", "HU", "HUGHES", "HYATT", "HYUNDAI", "IBM", "ICBC", "ICE", "ICU", "ID", "IE", "IEEE", "IFM", "IKANO", "IL", "IM", "IMAMAT", "IMDB", "IMMO", "IMMOBILIEN", "IN", "INDUSTRIES", "INFINITI", "INFO", "ING", "INK", "INSTITUTE", "INSURANCE", "INSURE", "INT", "INTEL", "INTERNATIONAL", "INTUIT", "INVESTMENTS", "IO", "IPIRANGA", "IQ", "IR", "IRISH", "IS", "ISELECT", "ISMAILI", "IST", "ISTANBUL", "IT", "ITAU", "ITV", "IVECO", "IWC", "JAGUAR", "JAVA", "JCB", "JCP", "JE", "JEEP", "JETZT", "JEWELRY", "JIO", "JLC", "JLL", "JM", "JMP", "JNJ", "JO", "JOBS", "JOBURG", "JOT", "JOY", "JP", "JPMORGAN", "JPRS", "JUEGOS", "JUNIPER", "KAUFEN", "KDDI", "KE", "KERRYHOTELS", "KERRYLOGISTICS", "KERRYPROPERTIES", "KFH", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KIA", "KIM", "KINDER", "KINDLE", "KITCHEN", "KIWI", "KM", "KN", "KOELN", "KOMATSU", "KOSHER", "KP", "KPMG", "KPN", "KR", "KRD", "KRED", "KUOKGROUP", "KW", "KY", "KYOTO", "KZ", "LA", "LACAIXA", "LADBROKES", "LAMBORGHINI", "LAMER", "LANCASTER", "LANCIA", "LANCOME", "LAND", "LANDROVER", "LANXESS", "LASALLE", "LAT", "LATINO", "LATROBE", "LAW", "LAWYER", "LB", "LC", "LDS", "LEASE", "LECLERC", "LEFRAK", "LEGAL", "LEGO", "LEXUS", "LGBT", "LI", "LIAISON", "LIDL", "LIFE", "LIFEINSURANCE", "LIFESTYLE", "LIGHTING", "LIKE", "LILLY", "LIMITED", "LIMO", "LINCOLN", "LINDE", "LINK", "LIPSY", "LIVE", "LIVING", "LIXIL", "LK", "LLC", "LOAN", "LOANS", "LOCKER", "LOCUS", "LOFT", "LOL", "LONDON", "LOTTE", "LOTTO", "LOVE", "LPL", "LPLFINANCIAL", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LTD", "LTDA", "LU", "LUNDBECK", "LUPIN", "LUXE", "LUXURY", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MACYS", "MADRID", "MAIF", "MAISON", "MAKEUP", "MAN", "MANAGEMENT", "MANGO", "MAP", "MARKET", "MARKETING", "MARKETS", "MARRIOTT", "MARSHALLS", "MASERATI", "MATTEL", "MBA", "MC", "MCKINSEY", "MD", "ME", "MED", "MEDIA", "MEET", "MELBOURNE", "MEME", "MEMORIAL", "MEN", "MENU", "MERCKMSD", "METLIFE", "MG", "MH", "MIAMI", "MICROSOFT", "MIL", "MINI", "MINT", "MIT", "MITSUBISHI", "MK", "ML", "MLB", "MLS", "MM", "MMA", "MN", "MO", "MOBI", "MOBILE", "MOBILY", "MODA", "MOE", "MOI", "MOM", "MONASH", "MONEY", "MONSTER", "MOPAR", "MORMON", "MORTGAGE", "MOSCOW", "MOTO", "MOTORCYCLES", "MOV", "MOVIE", "MOVISTAR", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MSD", "MT", "MTN", "MTR", "MU", "MUSEUM", "MUTUAL", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NAB", "NADEX", "NAGOYA", "NAME", "NATIONWIDE", "NATURA", "NAVY", "NBA", "NC", "NE", "NEC", "NET", "NETBANK", "NETFLIX", "NETWORK", "NEUSTAR", "NEW", "NEWHOLLAND", "NEWS", "NEXT", "NEXTDIRECT", "NEXUS", "NF", "NFL", "NG", "NGO", "NHK", "NI", "NICO", "NIKE", "NIKON", "NINJA", "NISSAN", "NISSAY", "NL", "NO", "NOKIA", "NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL", "NORTON", "NOW", "NOWRUZ", "NOWTV", "NP", "NR", "NRA", "NRW", "NTT", "NU", "NYC", "NZ", "OBI", "OBSERVER", "OFF", "OFFICE", "OKINAWA", "OLAYAN", "OLAYANGROUP", "OLDNAVY", "OLLO", "OM", "OMEGA", "ONE", "ONG", "ONL", "ONLINE", "ONYOURSIDE", "OOO", "OPEN", "ORACLE", "ORANGE", "ORG", "ORGANIC", "ORIGINS", "OSAKA", "OTSUKA", "OTT", "OVH", "PA", "PAGE", "PANASONIC", "PANERAI", "PARIS", "PARS", "PARTNERS", "PARTS", "PARTY", "PASSAGENS", "PAY", "PCCW", "PE", "PET", "PF", "PFIZER", "PG", "PH", "PHARMACY", "PHD", "PHILIPS", "PHONE", "PHOTO", "PHOTOGRAPHY", "PHOTOS", "PHYSIO", "PIAGET", "PICS", "PICTET", "PICTURES", "PID", "PIN", "PING", "PINK", "PIONEER", "PIZZA", "PK", "PL", "PLACE", "PLAY", "PLAYSTATION", "PLUMBING", "PLUS", "PM", "PN", "PNC", "POHL", "POKER", "POLITIE", "PORN", "POST", "PR", "PRAMERICA", "PRAXI", "PRESS", "PRIME", "PRO", "PROD", "PRODUCTIONS", "PROF", "PROGRESSIVE", "PROMO", "PROPERTIES", "PROPERTY", "PROTECTION", "PRU", "PRUDENTIAL", "PS", "PT", "PUB", "PW", "PWC", "PY", "QA", "QPON", "QUEBEC", "QUEST", "QVC", "RACING", "RADIO", "RAID", "RE", "READ", "REALESTATE", "REALTOR", "REALTY", "RECIPES", "RED", "REDSTONE", "REDUMBRELLA", "REHAB", "REISE", "REISEN", "REIT", "RELIANCE", "REN", "RENT", "RENTALS", "REPAIR", "REPORT", "REPUBLICAN", "REST", "RESTAURANT", "REVIEW", "REVIEWS", "REXROTH", "RICH", "RICHARDLI", "RICOH", "RIGHTATHOME", "RIL", "RIO", "RIP", "RMIT", "RO", "ROCHER", "ROCKS", "RODEO", "ROGERS", "ROOM", "RS", "RSVP", "RU", "RUGBY", "RUHR", "RUN", "RW", "RWE", "RYUKYU", "SA", "SAARLAND", "SAFE", "SAFETY", "SAKURA", "SALE", "SALON", "SAMSCLUB", "SAMSUNG", "SANDVIK", "SANDVIKCOROMANT", "SANOFI", "SAP", "SARL", "SAS", "SAVE", "SAXO", "SB", "SBI", "SBS", "SC", "SCA", "SCB", "SCHAEFFLER", "SCHMIDT", "SCHOLARSHIPS", "SCHOOL", "SCHULE", "SCHWARZ", "SCIENCE", "SCJOHNSON", "SCOR", "SCOT", "SD", "SE", "SEARCH", "SEAT", "SECURE", "SECURITY", "SEEK", "SELECT", "SENER", "SERVICES", "SES", "SEVEN", "SEW", "SEX", "SEXY", "SFR", "SG", "SH", "SHANGRILA", "SHARP", "SHAW", "SHELL", "SHIA", "SHIKSHA", "SHOES", "SHOP", "SHOPPING", "SHOUJI", "SHOW", "SHOWTIME", "SHRIRAM", "SI", "SILK", "SINA", "SINGLES", "SITE", "SJ", "SK", "SKI", "SKIN", "SKY", "SKYPE", "SL", "SLING", "SM", "SMART", "SMILE", "SN", "SNCF", "SO", "SOCCER", "SOCIAL", "SOFTBANK", "SOFTWARE", "SOHU", "SOLAR", "SOLUTIONS", "SONG", "SONY", "SOY", "SPACE", "SPIEGEL", "SPORT", "SPOT", "SPREADBETTING", "SR", "SRL", "SRT", "ST", "STADA", "STAPLES", "STAR", "STARHUB", "STATEBANK", "STATEFARM", "STATOIL", "STC", "STCGROUP", "STOCKHOLM", "STORAGE", "STORE", "STREAM", "STUDIO", "STUDY", "STYLE", "SU", "SUCKS", "SUPPLIES", "SUPPLY", "SUPPORT", "SURF", "SURGERY", "SUZUKI", "SV", "SWATCH", "SWIFTCOVER", "SWISS", "SX", "SY", "SYDNEY", "SYMANTEC", "SYSTEMS", "SZ", "TAB", "TAIPEI", "TALK", "TAOBAO", "TARGET", "TATAMOTORS", "TATAR", "TATTOO", "TAX", "TAXI", "TC", "TCI", "TD", "TDK", "TEAM", "TECH", "TECHNOLOGY", "TEL", "TELECITY", "TELEFONICA", "TEMASEK", "TENNIS", "TEVA", "TF", "TG", "TH", "THD", "THEATER", "THEATRE", "TIAA", "TICKETS", "TIENDA", "TIFFANY", "TIPS", "TIRES", "TIROL", "TJ", "TJMAXX", "TJX", "TK", "TKMAXX", "TL", "TM", "TMALL", "TN", "TO", "TODAY", "TOKYO", "TOOLS", "TOP", "TORAY", "TOSHIBA", "TOTAL", "TOURS", "TOWN", "TOYOTA", "TOYS", "TR", "TRADE", "TRADING", "TRAINING", "TRAVEL", "TRAVELCHANNEL", "TRAVELERS", "TRAVELERSINSURANCE", "TRUST", "TRV", "TT", "TUBE", "TUI", "TUNES", "TUSHU", "TV", "TVS", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UBANK", "UBS", "UCONNECT", "UG", "UK", "UNICOM", "UNIVERSITY", "UNO", "UOL", "UPS", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VACATIONS", "VANA", "VANGUARD", "VC", "VE", "VEGAS", "VENTURES", "VERISIGN", "VERSICHERUNG", "VET", "VG", "VI", "VIAJES", "VIDEO", "VIG", "VIKING", "VILLAS", "VIN", "VIP", "VIRGIN", "VISA", "VISION", "VISTA", "VISTAPRINT", "VIVA", "VIVO", "VLAANDEREN", "VN", "VODKA", "VOLKSWAGEN", "VOLVO", "VOTE", "VOTING", "VOTO", "VOYAGE", "VU", "VUELOS", "WALES", "WALMART", "WALTER", "WANG", "WANGGOU", "WARMAN", "WATCH", "WATCHES", "WEATHER", "WEATHERCHANNEL", "WEBCAM", "WEBER", "WEBSITE", "WED", "WEDDING", "WEIBO", "WEIR", "WF", "WHOSWHO", "WIEN", "WIKI", "WILLIAMHILL", "WIN", "WINDOWS", "WINE", "WINNERS", "WME", "WOLTERSKLUWER", "WOODSIDE", "WORK", "WORKS", "WORLD", "WOW", "WS", "WTC", "WTF", "XBOX", "XEROX", "XFINITY", "XIHUAN", "XIN", "XN--11B4C3D", "XN--1CK2E1B", "XN--1QQW23A", "XN--2SCRJ9C", "XN--30RR7Y", "XN--3BST00M", "XN--3DS443G", "XN--3E0B707E", "XN--3HCRJ9C", "XN--3OQ18VL8PN36A", "XN--3PXU8K", "XN--42C2D9A", "XN--45BR5CYL", "XN--45BRJ9C", "XN--45Q11C", "XN--4GBRIM", "XN--54B7FTA0CC", "XN--55QW42G", "XN--55QX5D", "XN--5SU34J936BGSG", "XN--5TZM5G", "XN--6FRZ82G", "XN--6QQ986B3XL", "XN--80ADXHKS", "XN--80AO21A", "XN--80AQECDR1A", "XN--80ASEHDB", "XN--80ASWG", "XN--8Y0A063A", "XN--90A3AC", "XN--90AE", "XN--90AIS", "XN--9DBQ2A", "XN--9ET52U", "XN--9KRT00A", "XN--B4W605FERD", "XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C", "XN--C1AVG", "XN--C2BR7G", "XN--CCK2B3B", "XN--CG4BKI", "XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD", "XN--CZR694B", "XN--CZRS0T", "XN--CZRU2D", "XN--D1ACJ3B", "XN--D1ALF", "XN--E1A4C", "XN--ECKVDTC9D", "XN--EFVY88H", "XN--ESTV75G", "XN--FCT429K", "XN--FHBEI", "XN--FIQ228C5HS", "XN--FIQ64B", "XN--FIQS8S", "XN--FIQZ9S", "XN--FJQ720A", "XN--FLW351E", "XN--FPCRJ9C3D", "XN--FZC2C9E2C", "XN--FZYS8D69UVGM", "XN--G2XX48C", "XN--GCKR3F0F", "XN--GECRJ9C", "XN--GK3AT1E", "XN--H2BREG3EVE", "XN--H2BRJ9C", "XN--H2BRJ9C8C", "XN--HXT814E", "XN--I1B6B1A6A2E", "XN--IMR513N", "XN--IO0A7I", "XN--J1AEF", "XN--J1AMH", "XN--J6W193G", "XN--JLQ61U9W7B", "XN--JVR189M", "XN--KCRX77D1X4A", "XN--KPRW13D", "XN--KPRY57D", "XN--KPU716F", "XN--KPUT3I", "XN--L1ACC", "XN--LGBBAT1AD8J", "XN--MGB9AWBF", "XN--MGBA3A3EJT", "XN--MGBA3A4F16A", "XN--MGBA7C0BBN0A", "XN--MGBAAKC7DVF", "XN--MGBAAM7A8H", "XN--MGBAB2BD", "XN--MGBAI9AZGQP6J", "XN--MGBAYH7GPA", "XN--MGBB9FBPOB", "XN--MGBBH1A", "XN--MGBBH1A71E", "XN--MGBC0A9AZCG", "XN--MGBCA7DZDO", "XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR", "XN--MGBGU82A", "XN--MGBI4ECEXP", "XN--MGBPL2FH", "XN--MGBT3DHD", "XN--MGBTX2B", "XN--MGBX4CD0AB", "XN--MIX891F", "XN--MK1BU44C", "XN--MXTQ1M", "XN--NGBC5AZD", "XN--NGBE9E0A", "XN--NGBRX", "XN--NODE", "XN--NQV7F", "XN--NQV7FS00EMA", "XN--NYQY26A", "XN--O3CW4H", "XN--OGBPF8FL", "XN--OTU796D", "XN--P1ACF", "XN--P1AI", "XN--PBT977C", "XN--PGBS0DH", "XN--PSSY2U", "XN--Q9JYB4C", "XN--QCKA1PMC", "XN--QXAM", "XN--RHQV96G", "XN--ROVU88B", "XN--RVC1E0AM3E", "XN--S9BRJ9C", "XN--SES554G", "XN--T60B56A", "XN--TCKWE", "XN--TIQ49XQYJ", "XN--UNUP4Y", "XN--VERMGENSBERATER-CTB", "XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB", "XN--VHQUV", "XN--VUQ861B", "XN--W4R85EL8FHU5DNRA", "XN--W4RS40L", "XN--WGBH1C", "XN--WGBL6A", "XN--XHQ521B", "XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A", "XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H", "XN--Y9A3AQ", "XN--YFRO4I67O", "XN--YGBI2AMMX", "XN--ZFR164B", "XPERIA", "XXX", "XYZ", "YACHTS", "YAHOO", "YAMAXUN", "YANDEX", "YE", "YODOBASHI", "YOGA", "YOKOHAMA", "YOU", "YOUTUBE", "YT", "YUN", "ZA", "ZAPPOS", "ZARA", "ZERO", "ZIP", "ZIPPO", "ZM", "ZONE", "ZUERICH", "ZW"});
}
```

The TLD list is from [here](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en).

Answer (score 2):

i found the correct solution

here:  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html

**here is example of code in java**

```
import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName;

public class splitDomain {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Split URL into protocol, domain, port and URI
            // here i am just extracting .com, .net, co.in letter on you can subtract this from your url and u will get exact url
          InternetDomainName it = InternetDomainName.from("www.vinay.com");
          System.out.println(it.publicSuffix().name());

          it = InternetDomainName.from("www.vinay.co.in");
          System.out.println(it.publicSuffix().name());

          it = InternetDomainName.from("www.vinay.co.uk");
          System.out.println(it.publicSuffix().name());

          //for subdomain
          String url = "firstsubdomain.developer.vinay.co.in";
          url = InternetDomainName.from(url).topPrivateDomain().name();
          it = InternetDomainName.from(url);
          String domainname = it.publicSuffix().name();
          System.out.println(domainname);
          String temp = url.replaceAll("."+domainname, "");
          System.out.println(temp);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume extension i.e. com, .in . my etc they come at third or second position

```
 String data[] = domainName.split("\\.");
 String domainLabel=""; 
 if(data.length==3 || data.length==4 ){ 
   domainLabel =data[1];
  }
 else if(data.length==2 ){ 
   domainLabel =data[0];
  }
```

Another approach is to have a array of all extensions..Split the string, where-ever you find the `EXTENSION` the DATA array ... `data[--index]` would work

Comment: extension could be .com or .co.in or .co.uk  or .in

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0, y=0;
        boolean check = false;
        String line = "**developer.ourdomain.co.in**";
        if ( line.contains("developer")){
            i = line.indexOf("developer");
            i += "developer".length()+1;
            y = i;
            check = true;
        }
        while( line.charAt(i++) != '.');
        if (check)
            System.out.println("**"+line.substring(y, i-1) + "**");
        else
            System.out.println(line.substring(y, i-1) + "**");
```

Comment: and what about this domains?

**developer.ourdomain.co.in**

**wowdomain.co.in**

Comment: please see examples in my question if you get exact answer like that than let me know here

Comment: domain name and sub domain could be anything and you have just written program about 'developer' dub domain. instead of 'developer' it could be anything

Comment: Notify that in your question, i didn't knew that

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CheckClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String domain="www.facebook.com";
        String host = domain
            .replaceAll("http://|https://|www.|ws://|wss://","")
            .replaceAll("/.*","")
            .split(".com")[0];

        System.out.println(host);
    }
}
```

If you give `"www.facebook.com"` then the answer will be `"facebook"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my static method for doing it:

```
public static String parseDomainNamefromUrl(String url) {
    if (url == null) return null;
    URL rawUrl = null;
    try {
        rawUrl = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - failed to create URL from url=" + url);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return url;
    }
    String host = rawUrl.getHost();
    InternetDomainName idn = InternetDomainName.from(host);
    while (idn.isTopPrivateDomain() == false && (idn.hasParent()) ) {
        idn = idn.parent();
    }
    String domain = idn.toString();
    if (idn.isUnderPublicSuffix()) {
        domain =idn.topPrivateDomain().toString();
    }
    System.out.println("Parsed domain: " + domain);
    return domain;
}
```