# How to get the real home page of a website

Tags: java, html

I want to know if there is any way to get the real URL of a webpage. For example, I have a website named `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm`, the real/main URL is `http://www.tutorialspoint.com` of its main page.

Now I have another website `http://www.sinhgad.edu/sinhgad-engineering-institutes/SEI-placement/index.html`, its main page URL is `http://www.sinhgad.edu/sinhgad-engineering-institutes/` in place of `http://www.sinhgad.edu/` only.

I want to get this main page URL or real URL in Java.

Comment: Which language? Javascript? jQuery? PHP?

Comment: In that case, show us some code.

Comment: @anny Be specific and add a language tag (java) to the question. So that people don't post answers of other languages.

Comment: Just get the string of the URL and split on /... Remove the last split, and rebuild the path

Comment: i have already tried split method. but that will only give the part of URL which i want statically. I want the path where the images scripts of that webpage are stored.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to get the Ip Address of the current Server running the Java app and InetAddress.getHostName() to get Hostname of the current Server name.

[source](http://crunchify.com/how-to-get-server-ip-address-and-hostname-in-java/).

Comment: sir it will give my local server name. i want the main URL of a website which is running on that website's server. I want this using java code because i need to download the image files, scripting files, CSS  and for that i need to get the exact path of that file.

Comment: Try this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url

Comment: no this will not give me the complete path . See there is a file "http://www.sinhgad.edu/sinhgad-engineering-institutes/main.js"  , i want to download that file but the problem is i am not getting the path of this file. because "http://www.sinhgad.edu/sinhgad-engineering-institutes/main.js" and "http://www.sinhgad.edu/main.js"  both file are present on the server of singhad university. And i want the first one.

Comment: actually i tried cases after splitting the URL which means i am checking that Is "http://www.sinhgad.edu/main.js" exist ? If not the check for  "http://www.sinhgad.edu/sinhgad-engineering-institutes/main.js" . But here my first condition is being true but i want second condition. Thats why i was asking Is there any way of getting the main 
URL of the webpage so that i can get the real path to be appended before file. and after that i don't need to check the condition which i am checking.