# How to Extract only the website name from a URL String not www. and .com with it

Tags: java, android, string, url

I just want to show the website name only.
I don't want to show ".com" or "us.cnn.com" or "www.bbc.co.uk" Just the name of the website Like "cnn" or "bbc" only.
**My code:**

```
private String getHostName(String urlInput) {
    urlInput = urlInput.toLowerCase();
    String hostName = urlInput;
    if (!urlInput.equals("")) {
        if (urlInput.startsWith("http") || urlInput.startsWith("https")) {
            try {
                URL netUrl = new URL(urlInput);
                String host = netUrl.getHost();
                if (host.startsWith("www")) {
                    hostName = host.substring("www".length() + 1);
                } else {
                    hostName = host;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                hostName = urlInput;
            }
        } else if (urlInput.startsWith("www")) {
            hostName = urlInput.substring("www".length() + 1);
        }
        return hostName;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Inputs**

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-39018776"
http://us.cnn.com/2017/02/18/politics/john-mccain-donald-trump-dictators/index.html"  
http://bigstory.ap.org/article/d5dd5962fc4d42b195117ca63e0ba9af/revived-rally-trump-turns-back-governing
```

**Outputs**

```
www.bbc.co.uk  
us.cnn.com  
bigstory.ap.org
```

I just want to extract the "bbc", "cnn" and "ap" name from it.

Comment: just split the url  at dot(.)  instead, it it contains http://  remove it

Comment: by using which method?

Comment: you can use `if (string.contains("http://"))`

Comment: thankyou ... plz give a proper code to eliminate all the other strings and just extracting the website name

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String mainUrl;
urlInput = urlInput.toLowerCase();
String hostName = urlInput;
String[] suburls = hostName.split("\\."); 
mainUrl=suburl[0]
if(suburls[0].contains("www")){  
    mainUrl=suburl[1];
  }
if(mainUrl.contains("http://"))
     mainUrl.replace("http://","");
else if(mainUrl.contains("https://")
    mainUrl.replace("https://","");
```

now the result should be in mainUrl

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)-class to extract the hostname from the string.

Example code :

```
public String getHostName(String url) {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String hostname = uri.getHost();
    // to provide faultproof result, check if not null then return only hostname, without www.
    if (hostname != null) {
        return hostname.startsWith("www.") ? hostname.substring(4) : hostname;
    }
    return hostname;
}
```

This above gives you the hostname, and is faultproof if your hostname does start with either `google.com/...` or `www.google.com/...`, which will return with 'google'.

If the given `url` is invalid (undefined hostname), it returns with null.

Comment: **URI uri = new URI(url);** is giving **Unhandled exception: java.net.URISyntaxException**

Comment: I have removed the error by using try and catch but the output is **us.cnn.com** and **bbc.co.uk** Not just cnn or bbc

Comment: If you want the top-level domain, you can split the string on "." and remove  second-level domain

Answer (score -1):

First convert your website URL to URI:

```
public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```

[Click here for full details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url).