# get only the website name from domain name of url

Tags: java, spring

I need to convert a list of URLS to their host name. SO tried the below mentioned code:

```
URL netUrl = new URL(url); 
String host = netUrl.getHost();
```

The above mentioned code is producing output as shown below:

```
a95-101-128-242.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com
a23-1-242-192.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
edge-video-shv-01-lht6.fbcdn.net
```

I want only the website name from the above output like as shown below:

```
akamaitechnologies
akamaitechnologies
fbcdn
```

Please someone help.
Thanks

Comment: `String[] parts = host.split("\\."); System.out.println(parts[parts.length-2]);`

Comment: what if the link is like google.co.uk, then only co will come.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a URL, use `java.net.URI`.  `java.net.URL` has a bunch of problems -- its `equals` method does a DNS lookup which means code using it can be vulnerable to denial of service attacks when used with untrusted inputs.

```
public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
  URI uri = new URI(url);
  String domain = uri.getHost();
  return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: its  returning same result like a95-101-128-242.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com

Comment: Yes, because you should replace this code: `domain.startsWith("www.")` with something that suits better for you! As far i can see your domains names are not starting with `www`. So change it and you should be ok.

Comment: You should have a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url