# how to parse an URL string to get domain only In Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't read Java, I need an answer in Kotlin and I have read a thread in here: [Get domain name from given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url)

say for example I have a string like this: `"http://www.myWebsite.com/profile"`

then how to programmatically get the domain name only in string like this `"myWebsite.com"` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is code from [pointed question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608008/2144352) just translated to Kotlin. You can try it in [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org).

```
import java.net.URI

fun main() {
    val url = "http://www.myWebsite.com/profile"
    val result = getDomainName(url)

    print(result)
}

fun getDomainName(url: String): String? {
    val uri = URI(url)
    val domain: String = uri.host
    return domain.removePrefix("www.")
}
```

Comment: It's much clearer to use removePrefix in this case`return domain.removePrefix("www.")`

Comment: It's not only Kotlin like requested in the question because URI is part of Java...