# How to extract website name from host name

Tags: android, kotlin, web

I am trying to get the website name from the host url(e.g "www.google.com" -> google, "facebook.com" -> facebook)
Currently I have this simple function:

```
   private fun getWebsiteNameFromUri(host: String): String {
        val cutString = host.substringBefore(".")
        
        return cutString.substringAfter(".")
    }
```

It doesn't work bad for many website, but of course there are MANY others that it's not working correctly, for example: "medium.com" just return com

I tried also count '.', and other approches but again, work for some and doesn't work for others.

There is any convention for extracting such a thing?
If not, How can I extract the website name, heavy regex is the only option?

Comment: I'm not a web developer so I'm not very familiar with all the possible cases, but shouldn't be a clear way of define the name of the website? If I go with your example. domain is the name and .google is the extension, doesn't it?    BTW I thought about getting the title/web site directy through the html using ```jsoup``` but it seems that many sites have a long title/missing the name part  @AdamMillerchip

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to put your link in `URL` class like this

```
URL url = new URL(address);
```

and then you may use

```
String host = url.getHost();
```

and [lot of other methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL)

edit: this question looks like [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url/40405173)...

Comment: The host that the function get it's after calling ```url.getHost```, it's returning the full host path( www.google.com)

Comment: I think this is actually the best idea, but if you pass a `String mediumCom = "medium.com";` this will throw a `MalformedURLException` due to the missing protocol. If one can make sure there will be a protocol, the `URL` will definitive be a good way to go.

Comment: @ScrapeW You narrow down the cases to be handled manually by doing this.

Comment: check out my edit and linked same question with multiple answers