# Android WebView navigation

Tags: android

I want to add news and weather app in webview. But jumping to anyther website from webview is not an option. How can I restrict a webview for a certain website.

Thanks.

Comment: I don´t understand your question

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain it. If I put www.weather.com in a webview and user clicks on some advertisement or try to share some thing via facebook or twitter. I should not allow. All the time the basic url has to be www.weather.com. User can browse anything within that url. Does this help ?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own WebViewClient:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.getHost().equals("weather.com")){
            // load link
            return false;
        }else{
            // block link
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

EDIT Note:
[an example of a getHost() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826122/1084554)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you might want to implement your own [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation).  That will allow you to handle the page navigation.  Check out [the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation) for a tutorial from Google.

Answer (score -1):

```
viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        //Block all URL accesses.
        return false;
    }
});
```

That should prevent access to anything. You need to handle specific URL's in this function if you want to allow them.