# How I can change the particular URL into the sub URL

Tags: java, android

I have the following URL

http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

I want to break this into below URL-

www.androidexample.com

How can write code for this?

Comment: I want to implement this in android webservice

Comment: why you want to break....as webservice wont work without parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String uriStr = "http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90";
String host = new URI(uriStr).getHost();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
URI uri = new URI("http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90");
    System.out.println("URI      : " + uri);
    System.out.println(uri.getHost());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the `//` and for the first `/` in the url.

e.g.

```
int slashslash = url.indexOf("//") + 2;
domain = url.substring(slashslash, url.indexOf('/', slashslash));
```

It was answered here: [What is the fastest way to get the domain/host name from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826061/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-domain-host-name-from-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get domain name of particular URL. just pass your URL in below code you can get domain or sub URL.

```
String url="http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90";
String subUrl = getDomainName(url);


public static String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
URI uri = new URI(url);
String domain = uri.getHost();
return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```