# How to split URL and take only the host names

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to split URLs, for example `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` and take only `stackoverflow.com`. How can I do this in Java without using the built in function `getHost()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826061/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-domain-host-name-from-a-url

Comment: Why not use the tools of the language? Why reinvent a URL parser when you already have one, that has been fully tested, and is known to work?

Comment: `String hostName = url.split("/{1,}")[1];`

Answer (score 0):

1. One thing you can do is use String#replaceAll. I know it's not what you want but off the bat it's a **decent** way to do it.

```java
String uri = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";

if (uri.contains("https://")) {
    uri = uri.replaceAll("https://", "");
}

if (uri.contains("http://")) {
    uri = uri.replaceAll("http://", "");
}

int indexOfBackwardsSlash = uri.indexOf("/");

if (indexOfBackwardsSlash != -1) {
    uri = uri.substring(0, indexOfBackwardsSlash);
}
```

2. Use URI#getPath.

```java
URI uri = URI.create("https...");

String path = uri.getPath();
```

Comment: The getPath() returns the path after the host - you means getHost more likely ?

Comment: Actually getPath returns the rawPath, which is; "The string returned by this method is equal to that returned by the getRawPath method except that all sequences of escaped octets are decoded.".

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your URL into a String , there is this option :

```
public static void main(String []args){
  String str ="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";
  String[] parts = str.split("/");
  String part1 = parts[0]; //https:
  String part2 = parts[1]; //'nothing'
  String part3 = parts[2]; //stackoverflow.com
  String part4 = parts[3]; //questions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regular expressions:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UrlRegex {
     public static void main(String []args){
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("//([^/]*)"); //match everything between "//" and "/"
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(url);
        if (m.find()) {
            String hostname = m.group(1);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Won't match stackoverflow.com/questions/ !

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:http)s?://)?(?<hostGroup>[^/:]+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/");

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("hostGroup"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found! Invalid URL ^^");
    }
```

The above will find **stackoverflow.com** for the following urls strings :

- https://**stackoverflow.com**/questions/
- http://**stackoverflow.com**/questions/
- **stackoverflow.com**/questions/
- **stackoverflow.com**:80/questions/
- **stackoverflow.com**/
- **stackoverflow.com**

I guess that's for practicing regex ? Otherwise, prefer using the standard APIs whenever possible - (in your case `URI#getHost()` !)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you are getting the proper URL format than you can just substring it preferred places.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";
        System.out.println(getHostFast(url));
    }
    public static String getHostFast(String url) {
        String subbed = url.substring(url.indexOf('/') + 2);
        return subbed.substring(0, subbed.indexOf('/'));
    }
```

The error prof method would need to contain additional check (for example if the next '/' exists after dropping `http://`.