# RegEx : Grab domain after sub domain (if there is one) from URL

Tags: regex

This is my problem: http://regexr.com?2temn

I'm sure it's pretty simple for some of you regex masters.

Cheers!

Comment: Please post the problem here instead of linking it to an external page that might be gone soon. People without Flash players (iOS, anyone?), can't see the problem at all. And even if I turn off my Flash blocker and see the site, I still don't understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: you should rephrase your question. links to an external sites are fine but the question must be comprehensive also without this additional info. Also name where you're using this regex. There are many flavors of regex...

Comment: @Tim confirm not working with iOS

Comment: @Tim, why do you use a flash blocker?

Comment: @Christopher: Because all the annoying ads are Flash ads. There is not much useful Flash content around IMO. Regexr being an exception, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works:

```
(?<=\.|)\w+\.\w+$
```

Tested only with PHP.

Comment: can you latch domain with "-" inside ?

Comment: Works only for `http://www.example.com` or `http://sub1.sub2.example.com` etc but fails if there's trailing / or path in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Grab domain after (possible) sub domain
is in fact the same as
grab domain before top level domain

it's just get the domain name from a URL.

possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/863297/397667)

Answer (score 1):

Regex ***(generic form)*** :

`/^(?:https?://)?(?:([\w_.-]+?).)*[\w_-]+\.\w+.+$/i`

Test :

```
http://subdomain.domain.tld/foo/bar.html      => One match    (subdomain)
http://subdomain.subdomain2.domain.tld/bar    => Two submatches (subdomain, subdomain2)
http://justdomain.tld                         => NO match
```

Tested with C#.
**C# version of the regex** :

```
 ^(?:http://)?(?:([\w+_.-]+?)\.)*[\w+_-]+\.\w+.+$
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%5B%5Cw_.-%5D%2B%3F%29.%29*%5B%5Cw_-%5D%2B%5C.%5Cw%2B.%2B%24&i=foo.bar.co.uk%0D%0Asomething.co.uk%0D%0Asubdomain.domain.co.tld&o=im)

Comment: This would not match https sites.

Comment: I have just added it the support for https sites. But what about other protocols (ftp, irc etc) ? pagewil didn't precize.

Comment: This does not work if the tld is of two words. Like something.co.uk

Comment: @Kannaiyan Please see the working demo in the post with `.co.uk` domains.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(\w+\.\w+)[\r\n]+
```

It matches string with dot inside before new line character

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your version slightly:

```
(?:\.|)\w+(\.\w+){1,}
```

I just made the trailing ".xyz" part be a separate token to loop one or many times ("`{1,}`").