# Is it possible to mask/ hide the lengthy URL and just to display the domain name alone?

Tags: java, php, javascript, url, web

Is it possible to mask/ hide the lengthy URL and just to display the domain name alone in address bar in the browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome?

Please suggest.

Regards
Gourav

Comment: Which language? You can use regular expressions to do this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863297/regular-expression-to-retrieve-domain-tld

Comment: What is it youa re trying to achieve ?

Comment: User should see the Domain name alone in the address bar even when he changes the pages in the website.

Comment: @Raze2dust: Thanks for your reply... the link that you have given is not related to my query.

Comment: If you aren't aware that all your pages except homepage will not be indexed by google - do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use AJAX for this. In your index file, include a javascript file which uses XMLHttpRequest (or you can use something like jQuery.load if you don't want to go so low level) to load your content. With jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

However, do not do so lightly - this can break search engine optimization and many other things as some people may have javascript off etc.

And remember, this is a very simplified example - you'd have to take care of things like external URIs (CSRF protection in browsers means you can't XMLHttpRequest another domain). Maybe you could add a CSS class called `link_internal` and then add that in your jQuery selector etc.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do that.
It's against the very basics of the technology and usability.

Every page should have its unique address, letting users bookmark it, send link to a friend, **navigate your site after all**!

Comment: Additional reading about the usability of URLs: [URL as UI](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990321.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
domain = re.match(r'https?://(?:www\.)?([^/]+)', full_url).group(1)
```

This regex extracts the domain - without `www.` but any other subdomains if they exist.
It uses the python `re` module but it should be easy to adept it to another language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... Actually what i am try is that the "User should see the Domain name alone in the address bar even when he changes the pages in the website".

Comment: This is not possible without using frames which are not very accessible and tend to annoy users. Better use a nice url structure so you don't have to be ashamed of your url.