# regexp dangling meta character near index 0

Tags: java, regex, hive

I've got some problems with regexp function in hive. 
I hope to find the top level domain in the list examples:

```
www.whatever.com
www.iam.com.uk
mobile.who.com.us
```

in this case, i should get the result of "`whatever, iam, who`" so I choose to look reverse, and write regular expression:

```
*\.([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+)+(\.[a-z]+)?$
```

**meaning that I only want to look at the last 2 or 3 items in the url**.
But it returned a dangling error.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `^` instead of `*` for the first character in the regex?  `^` means start-of-string.  Or maybe you mean `.*` to match any number of characters before the first `.`?  Also you have an unclosed group.

Comment: I tried to put .* at the beginning, but that return url like 'm.whatever.com' which means it only replace one character instead of any number at front

Comment: `^\w+\.(\w+)(?:\.\w+)+$` will give you the expected result in group 1 for the examples you provided.  However, it is not a general regex for extracting the top-level domain from a hostname.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to want to get the 2nd portion of the URL always. So why not do that directly?

```
[a-z]+?\.([a-z]+)?\.
```

1. This checks for 1 or more characters lazily.
2. Then a `.` dot.
3. Then it captures 1 or more characters lazily until a dot.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oS9jL7/1)

Comment: The reason I didn't do that is there could be a possibility when "mobile.sports.whatever.com" happens

Comment: @QiNie: If your goal really is to extract the domain name (and not simply fix the error in your original regex), please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863297/regular-expression-to-retrieve-domain-tld) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url) for ideas.