# How to extract top-level domain name (TLD) from URL

Tags: python, url, parsing, dns, extract

how would you extract the domain name from a URL, excluding any subdomains?

My initial simplistic attempt was:

```
'.'.join(urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc.split('.')[-2:])
```

This works for http://www.foo.com, but not http://www.foo.com.au.
Is there a way to do this properly without using special knowledge about valid TLDs (Top Level Domains) or country codes (because they change).

thanks

Comment: A related question previously on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Comment: +1: The "simplistic attempt" in this question works well for me, even if it ironically didn't work for the author.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406300/python-urlparse-extract-domain-name-without-subdomain

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, there is no "intrinsic" way of knowing that (e.g.) `zap.co.it` is a subdomain (because Italy's registrar DOES sell domains such as `co.it`) while `zap.co.uk` *isn't* (because the UK's registrar DOESN'T sell domains such as `co.uk`, but only like `zap.co.uk`).

You'll just have to use an auxiliary table (or online source) to tell you which TLD's behave peculiarly like UK's and Australia's -- there's no way of divining that from just staring at the string without such extra semantic knowledge (of course it can change eventually, but if you can find a good online source that source will also change accordingly, one hopes!-).

Answer (score 67):

Here's a great python module someone wrote to solve this problem after seeing this question:
https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

The module looks up TLDs in the [Public Suffix List](https://www.publicsuffix.org/), mantained by Mozilla volunteers

Quote:

> `tldextract` on the other hand knows what all gTLDs [*Generic Top-Level Domains*]
>   and ccTLDs [*Country Code Top-Level Domains*] look like
>   by looking up the currently living ones according to the [Public Suffix
>   List](https://www.publicsuffix.org/). So, given a URL, it knows its subdomain from its domain, and its
>   domain from its country code.

Comment: This worked for me where `tld` failed (it marked a valid URL as invalid).

Comment: Lost too much time thinking about the problem, should have known and used this from the start.

Answer (score 42):

Using [this file of effective tlds](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) which [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url/569176#569176) found on Mozilla's website:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from urlparse import urlparse

# load tlds, ignore comments and empty lines:
with open("effective_tld_names.dat.txt") as tld_file:
    tlds = [line.strip() for line in tld_file if line[0] not in "/\n"]

def get_domain(url, tlds):
    url_elements = urlparse(url)[1].split('.')
    # url_elements = ["abcde","co","uk"]

    for i in range(-len(url_elements), 0):
        last_i_elements = url_elements[i:]
        #    i=-3: ["abcde","co","uk"]
        #    i=-2: ["co","uk"]
        #    i=-1: ["uk"] etc

        candidate = ".".join(last_i_elements) # abcde.co.uk, co.uk, uk
        wildcard_candidate = ".".join(["*"] + last_i_elements[1:]) # *.co.uk, *.uk, *
        exception_candidate = "!" + candidate

        # match tlds: 
        if (exception_candidate in tlds):
            return ".".join(url_elements[i:]) 
        if (candidate in tlds or wildcard_candidate in tlds):
            return ".".join(url_elements[i-1:])
            # returns "abcde.co.uk"

    raise ValueError("Domain not in global list of TLDs")

print get_domain("http://abcde.co.uk", tlds)
```

results in:

```
abcde.co.uk
```

I'd appreciate it if someone let me know which bits of the above could be rewritten in a more pythonic way. For example, there must be a better way of iterating over the `last_i_elements` list, but I couldn't think of one. I also don't know if `ValueError` is the best thing to raise. Comments?

Comment: If you need to call getDomain() often in practice, such as extracting domains from a large log file, I would recommend that you make tlds a set, e.g. tlds = set([line.strip() for line in tldFile if line[0] not in "/\n"]).  This gives you constant time lookup for each of those checks for whether some item is in tlds.  I saw a speedup of about 1500 times for the lookups (set vs. list) and for my entire operation extracting domains from a ~20 million line log file, about a 60 times speedup (6 minutes down from 6 hours).

Comment: This is awesome! Just one more question: is that `effective_tld_names.dat` file also updated for new domains such as `.amsterdam`, `.vodka` and `.wtf`?

Comment: The Mozilla public suffix list gets regular maintenance, yes, and now has multiple Python libraries which include it.  See http://publicsuffix.org/ and the other answers on this page.

Comment: Some updates to get this right in 2021: the file is now called `public_suffix_list.dat`, and Python will complain if you don't specify that it should read the file as UTF8. Specify the encoding explicitly: `with open("public_suffix_list.dat", encoding="utf8") as tld_file`

Answer (score 42):

Using python `tld`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tld

#### Install

```
pip install tld
```

#### Get the TLD name as string from the URL given

```
from tld import get_tld
print get_tld("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

> co.uk

**or without protocol**

```
from tld import get_tld

get_tld("www.google.co.uk", fix_protocol=True)
```

> co.uk

#### Get the TLD as an object

```
from tld import get_tld

res = get_tld("http://some.subdomain.google.co.uk", as_object=True)

res
# 'co.uk'

res.subdomain
# 'some.subdomain'

res.domain
# 'google'

res.tld
# 'co.uk'

res.fld
# 'google.co.uk'

res.parsed_url
# SplitResult(
#     scheme='http',
#     netloc='some.subdomain.google.co.uk',
#     path='',
#     query='',
#     fragment=''
# )
```

#### Get the first level domain name as string from the URL given

```
from tld import get_fld

get_fld("http://www.google.co.uk")
# 'google.co.uk'
```

Comment: This will become more unreliable with the new gTLDs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing at this. I guess, when it comes to the point that new gTLDs are actually being used, a proper fix could come into the ``tld`` package.

Comment: Thank you @ArturBarseghyan ! Its very easy to use with Python. But I am using it now for enterprise grade product, is it a good idea to continue using it even if gTLDs are not being supported? 
If yes, when do you think gTLDs will be supported ?  
Thank you again.

Comment: @Akshay Patil:

As stated above, when it comes to the point that gTLDs are intensively used, a proper fix (if possible) would arrive in the package.

In the meanwhile, if you're concerned much about gTLDs, you can always catch the ``tld.exceptions.TldDomainNotFound`` exception and proceed anyway with whatever you were doing, even if domain hasn't been found.

Comment: Is it just me, or does `tld.get_tld()` actually return a fully qualified domain name, not a top level domain?

Comment: `get_tld("http://www.google.co.uk", as_object=True).extension`

would print out: "co.uk"

Comment: Having URL parsing functionality built in is nice, I suppose, but *requiring* input to be a URL seems misdirected.  If I want to handle host names for SSH or whatever, forcing them to be URLs (or "accepting" that the protocol is "missing") is just weird.

Comment: triplee: It works without protocol as well. see the updated example.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many TLD's.  Here's the list:

http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Here's another list

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Here's another list

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/

Comment: That doesn't help, because it doesn't tell you which ones have an "extra level", like co.uk.

Comment: Lennart: It helps, U can wrap them to be optional, within a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Until get_tld is updated for all the new ones, I pull the tld from the error. Sure it's bad code but it works.

```
def get_tld():
  try:
    return get_tld(self.content_url)
  except Exception, e:
    re_domain = re.compile("Domain ([^ ]+) didn't match any existing TLD name!");
    matchObj = re_domain.findall(str(e))
    if matchObj:
      for m in matchObj:
        return m
    raise e
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I handle it:

```
if not url.startswith('http'):
    url = 'http://'+url
website = urlparse.urlparse(url)[1]
domain = ('.').join(website.split('.')[-2:])
match = re.search(r'((www\.)?([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}))', domain, re.I)
if not match:
    sys.exit(2)
elif not match.group(0):
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: There is a domain called .travel. It won't work with the above code.

Answer (score -1):

In Python I used to use **tldextract** until it failed with a url like `www.mybrand.sa.com` parsing it as `subdomain='order.mybrand', domain='sa', suffix='com'`!!

So finally, I decided to write this method

IMPORTANT NOTE: this only works with urls that have a subdomain in them. This isn't meant to replace more advanced libraries like **tldextract**

```
def urlextract(url):
  url_split=url.split(".")
  if len(url_split) <= 2:
      raise Exception("Full url required with subdomain:",url)
  return {'subdomain': url_split[0], 'domain': url_split[1], 'suffix': ".".join(url_split[2:])}
```