# Get subdomain from URL using Python

Tags: python, string, url

For example, the address is:

`Address = http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page`

I want to save the subdomain into a variable so i could do like so;

```
print SubAddr
>> lol1
```

Comment: This questions should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/python-extract-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`urlparse.urlparse` will split the URL into protocol, location, port, etc. You can then split the location by `.` to get the subdomain.

```
import urlparse
url = urlparse.urlparse(address)
subdomain = url.hostname.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Works very good. I used it like so Node = urlparse.urlparse(address).hostname.split('.')[0]

Comment: What if it's an IP address? And what if it has a second level subdomain?

Comment: Subdomains may contain multiple dots so `api.test` is also valid, just keep this in mind. If you want a good package for doing this check `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract`.

Comment: This is actually a pretty bad answer. It fails if there's no subdomain, returning the domain instead. It fails for IP addresses (ok, fine), and it fails for multiple subdomains, like `web.host1.google.com`.

Comment: Agree with what is said above.  It only works well in a specific circumstance.

Comment: in python 3.x you need to import this via `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Comment: in general, as stated in other answers and their comments, manually splitting on `.` is unsafe b/c TLD's can have a `.` in the middle, like `.co.uk` vs `.com`. You need a list of TLDs to do this reliably

Answer (score 30):

Package [tldextract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract) makes this task very easy, and then you can use **urlparse** as suggested if you need any further information:

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> tldextract.extract("http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page"
ExtractResult(subdomain='lol1', domain='domain', suffix='com')
>>> tldextract.extract("http://sub.lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page"
ExtractResult(subdomain='sub.lol1', domain='domain', suffix='com')
>>> urlparse.urlparse("http://sub.lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='sub.lol1.domain.com:8888', path='/some/page', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Note that **tldextract** properly handles sub-domains.

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you.

Comment: great  answer, should be voted as the best one :) thanks Lluis

Answer (score 5):

Modified version of the fantastic answer here: [How to extract top-level domain name (TLD) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/python-extract-domain-name-from-url/1069780#1069780)

*You will need the list of effective tlds from [**here**](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1)*

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from urlparse import urlparse

# load tlds, ignore comments and empty lines:
with open("effective_tld_names.dat.txt") as tldFile:
    tlds = [line.strip() for line in tldFile if line[0] not in "/\n"]

class DomainParts(object):
    def __init__(self, domain_parts, tld):
        self.domain = None
        self.subdomains = None
        self.tld = tld
        if domain_parts:
            self.domain = domain_parts[-1]
            if len(domain_parts) > 1:
                self.subdomains = domain_parts[:-1]

def get_domain_parts(url, tlds):
    urlElements = urlparse(url).hostname.split('.')
    # urlElements = ["abcde","co","uk"]
    for i in range(-len(urlElements),0):
        lastIElements = urlElements[i:]
        #    i=-3: ["abcde","co","uk"]
        #    i=-2: ["co","uk"]
        #    i=-1: ["uk"] etc

        candidate = ".".join(lastIElements) # abcde.co.uk, co.uk, uk
        wildcardCandidate = ".".join(["*"]+lastIElements[1:]) # *.co.uk, *.uk, *
        exceptionCandidate = "!"+candidate

        # match tlds: 
        if (exceptionCandidate in tlds):
            return ".".join(urlElements[i:]) 
        if (candidate in tlds or wildcardCandidate in tlds):
            return DomainParts(urlElements[:i], '.'.join(urlElements[i:]))
            # returns ["abcde"]

    raise ValueError("Domain not in global list of TLDs")

domain_parts = get_domain_parts("http://sub2.sub1.example.co.uk:80",tlds)
print "Domain:", domain_parts.domain
print "Subdomains:", domain_parts.subdomains or "None"
print "TLD:", domain_parts.tld
```

**Gives you:**

```
Domain: example
Subdomains: ['sub2', 'sub1']
TLD: co.uk
```

Comment: Updated link to "list of effective tlds": https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List#TLD_Lists, http://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 4):

A very basic approach, without any sanity checking could look like:

```
address = 'http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page'

host = address.partition('://')[2]
sub_addr = host.partition('.')[0]

print sub_addr
```

This of course assumes that when you say 'subdomain' you mean the first part of a host name, so in the following case, 'www' would be the subdomain:

http://www.google.com/

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is in:
http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

for example:
`".".join(urlparse('http://www.my.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html').netloc.split(".")[:-2])`

Will do the job for you (will return "www.my")

Comment: This assumes that the main domain name has two parts - which will fall down in certain cases, e.g. `.co.uk` addresses. Besides the UK, Israel, Brasil and Japan all have formal second level domains, and there are probably others.

Comment: My answer deals with this problem using a list of valid TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

First of All import ***tldextract***, as this splits the URL into its constituents like: *subdomain. domain, and suffix*.

```
import tldextract
```

Then declare a variable (say ext) that stores the results of the query. We also have to provide it with the URL in parenthesis with double quotes. As shown below:

```
ext = tldextract.extract("http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page")
```

If we simply try to run ext variable, the output will be:

```
ExtractResult(subdomain='lol1', domain='domain', suffix='com')
```

Then if you want to use only subdomain or domain or suffix, then use any of the below code, respectively.

```
ext.subdomain
```

The result will be:

```
'lol1'
```

```
ext.domain
```

The result will be:

```
'domain'
```

```
ext.suffix
```

The result will be:

```
'com'
```

Also, if you want to store the results only of subdomain in a variable, then use the code below:

```
Sub_Domain = ext.subdomain
```

Then Print Sub_Domain

```
Sub_Domain
```

The result will be:

```
'lol1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Standardize all domains to start with www. unless they have a subdomain.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
    
def has_subdomain(url):
    if len(url.split('.')) > 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

domain = urlparse(url).netloc
        
if not has_subdomain(url):
        domain_name = 'www.' + domain
        url = urlparse(url).scheme + '://' + domain
```

Answer (score 0):

For extracting the hostname, I'd use urlparse from urllib2:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlparse
>>> a = "http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page"
>>> urlparse.urlparse(a).hostname
'lol1.domain.com'
```

As to how to extract the subdomain, you need to cover for the case that there FQDN could be longer. How you do this would depend on your purposes. I might suggest stripping off the two right most components.

E.g.

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse(a).hostname.rpartition('.')[0].rpartition('.')[0]
'lol1'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract for this problem...

It's easy.

```
>>> ext = tldextract.extract('http://forums.bbc.co.uk')
>>> (ext.subdomain, ext.domain, ext.suffix)
('forums', 'bbc', 'co.uk')
```

Answer (score 0):

[tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/) separate the TLD from the registered domain and subdomains of a URL.

Installation

```
pip install tldextract
```

For the current question:

```
import tldextract

address = 'http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page'
domain = tldextract.extract(address).domain
print("Extracted domain name : ", domain)
```

**The output:**

```
Extracted domain name :  domain
```

In addition, [there](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/tldextract.extract/) is a number of examples which is extremely related with the usage of tldextract.extract side.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3 (I'm using 3.9 to be specific), you can do the following:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

address = 'http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page'

url = urlparse(address)

url.hostname.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def extract_domain(domain):
   domain = re.sub('http(s)?://|(\:|/)(.*)|','', domain)
   matches = re.findall("([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$", domain)
   if matches:
       return matches[0]
   else:
       return domain

def extract_subdomains(domain):
   subdomains = domain = re.sub('http(s)?://|(\:|/)(.*)|','', domain)
   domain = extract_domain(subdomains)
   subdomains = re.sub('\.?'+domain,'', subdomains)
   return subdomains
```

Example to fetch subdomains:

```
print(extract_subdomains('http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page'))
print(extract_subdomains('kota-tangerang.kpu.go.id'))
```

Outputs:

```
lol1
kota-tangerang
```

Example to fetch domain

```
print(extract_domain('http://lol1.domain.com:8888/some/page'))
print(extract_domain('kota-tangerang.kpu.go.id'))
```

Outputs:

```
domain.com
kpu.go.id
```