# Parsing URLs in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, url-parsing

I'm having trouble parsing urls in Postgres. I have a database full of customers and urls associated with them. I need an array of the unique domains associated with each customer. I'd love to be able to do the parsing in my query instead of dumping my results to Python and parsing it there.

In the postgres docs I found this, but can't figure out how to incorporate it into my query:

```
SELECT alias, description, token FROM ts_debug('http://example.com/stuff/index.html');  

  alias   |  description  |            token               
----------+---------------+------------------------------  
 protocol | Protocol head | http://  
 url      | URL           | example.com/stuff/index.html  
 host     | Host          | example.com  
 url_path | URL path      | /stuff/index.html
```

(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-parsers.html)

I'm starting with a table, like this:

```
customer_id | url 
-------------+--------------------   
000001      | www.example.com/fish  
000001      | www.example.com/potato  
000001      | www.potato.com/artichoke
000002      | www.otherexample.com
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT customer_id, array_agg(url)
FROM customer_url_table
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Which gives me:

```
customer_id | unique_domains
-----------------------------
000001      | {www.example.com/fish, www.example.com/potato, www.potato.com/greenery}
000002      | {www.otherexample.com}
```

I want a table like this:

```
customer_id | unique_domains
-----------------------------
000001      | {example.com, potato.com}
000002      | {otherexample.com}
```

Working on a PostgreSQL 9.3.3 database that lives on AWS.

Comment: Why using the manual of version 8.3 when working on version 9.3? A lot has changed between 8.3 and 9.3

Comment: @frank-heikens, thanks for pointing that out. The relevant portion in this doc is the same in 9.3 as 8.3, so I've just updated the link to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document you linked above is for use with a *Postgres text search parser*. That requires a separate configuration to setup, and may be more overhead and/or a different sort of thing than you are looking for.

If you do want to go that route, to setup a text parser, you can find more info here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtsconfig.html

However, if you want to do the parsing inline in *Postgres*, I would recommend using a procedural *Postgres* language, where you can import parsing libraries in that language.

You mentioned *Python*, so you could use *PL/Python* and a url parsing library such as *urlparse* (called *urllib.parse* in Python 3).

[More info about *urlparse*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

That includes this example code:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
>>> o   
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.scheme
'http'
>>> o.port
80
>>> o.geturl()
'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
```

Going beyond that example, you can get the hostname with the *hostname* member:

```
>>> print o.hostname
www.cwi.nl
```

If you want properly parse out just the domain name (there are lots of edge cases and variants -- i.e. minus the *www* and any other assorted parts that may be there -- an approach such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6926141/3583500) would be best.

For more information about setting up *PL/Python*, you can go here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpython.html

So, that's how you could do the parsing in *Postgres*

> instead of dumping my results to Python and parsing it there

It ends up coming a bit full circle with the *PL/Python*, but if you really want to do the parsing within SQL (especially for performance reasons, say, across a large data set), going with *PL/Python* may be worth the extra effort.

Comment: Yep, that'd be my suggestion too. If performance is crucial you could instead write a simple C extension to wrap a C library that does URL parsing and return a result set from it, but that's a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I didn't know PL/Python was a thing. I've been looking for a decent tutorial in creating functions and doing SQL scripting in general, but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function

```
create or replace function fn_get_url_path(in_link text) returns text as
$$
begin
  return (select token
          from (select token, alias
                from ts_parse('default', in_link)
                       natural join ts_token_type('default')) tokens
          where tokens.alias = 'url_path');

end;
$$ language PLpgSQL;
```

Then use the function:

```
select fn_get_url_path(column1)
from (values ('https://www.example.com'),
         ('https://www.example.com/test.html'),
         ('https://www.example.com/test?a=1'),
         ('this doesnt work and will return null')) a
```

To get the result:

```
/*
  null,
  /test.html
  /test?a=1
  null
*/
```