# splitting a full url into parts

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a url into parts so that I can work with these separately.

For e.g. the url:

`'https://api.somedomain.co.uk/api/addresses?postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34'`

How can I split this into:
1) the source/origin (i.e. protocol + subdomain + domain)
2) path '/api/addresses'
3) Query:  '?postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlparse` library, found in `urllib` in Python3, is designed for this. Example adapted from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('https://api.somedomain.co.uk/api/addresses?postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34')
>>> o   
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='api.somedomain.co.uk', path='/api/addresses', params='', query='postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34', fragment='')
>>> o.scheme
'http'
>>> o.port
None
>>> o.geturl()
'https://api.somedomain.co.uk/api/addresses?postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34'
```

In order to get host, path and query, the API is straighforward:

```
>>> print(o.hostname, o.path, o.query)
```

Returns:

```
api.somedomain.co.uk /api/addresses postcode=XXSDF&houseNo=34
```

In order to get the subdomain itself, [the only way seems to split by `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925825/get-subdomain-from-url-using-python).

---

Note that the `urllib.parse.urlsplit` should be used instead `urlparse`, according to the documentation:

> This should generally be used instead of urlparse(https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) if the more recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of the path portion of the URL (see RFC 2396) is wanted

Comment: Thanks - I love how python has a tool for everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use python's urlparse.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
>>> o   
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.scheme
'http'
>>> o.port
80
>>> o.geturl()
'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the stdlib module `urlparse` on Python 2, or `urllib.parse` on Python 3. This will split the URL up more finely than you're asking for, but it's not difficult to put the pieces back together again.