# The best way to get the naked domain

Tags: python, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python extract domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/python-extract-domain-name-from-url)

I'm thinking about the best way to get a naked domain from an host.

```
def naked_domain(host):
    """Returns a naked domain from an host.

    Doctests:
      >>> naked_domain("google.com")
      'google.com'
      >>> naked_domain("www.google.com")
      'google.com'
      >>> naked_domain("xxx.www.google.com")
      'google.com'
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Oddly there is nothing in `urlparse` for this?

Comment: What do you want to happen for TLDs where there's a second level hierarchy?  e.g. what should `www.bbc.co.uk` return?

Comment: @Mark Longair: Returns `bbc.co.uk`

Comment: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

Answer (score 2):

The [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module can split it up into it's components. You can then access the domain with 'netloc'.

Comment: from the OP's examples, he wants the url stripped to hostname.tld, without the subdomains. urlparse is unable to do that. The only way to get what he wants is to use a list of valid TLDs. This problem has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/python-extract-domain-name-from-url/1069780#1069780

Comment: OP is looking to split full domain, not just get full domain from netloc