# Regex not matching URL in Python

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url)

I want to extract the website from an URL, i.e. `console.aws.amazon.com` from the following URL.

```
>>> ts
'https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#s=Instances,EC2 Management Console,12/3/2012 4:34:57 PM,11,0,,25806'
>>> re.match(ts,'(")?http(s)?://(.*?)/').group(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
re.match(ts,'(")?http(s)?://(.*?)/').group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I [tried this regular expression in JS](http://regexpal.com/) and it worked. Any idea why this matches in JS, but it doesn't work in Python?

Comment: Regex or regexp if you like, but not regrex. Short for _Reg_ ular _Ex_ pression.

Comment: Vote for reopen - as this specific question is asking for a regular expression to extract the domain. The comment below the answer clarifies why urlparse is not ideal *in this case* - namely that an exe will be exported, and the less includes the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing your match incorrect.
Python doco say's:

```
re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

You are doing:

```
re.match(string, pattern)
```

So simply change it to:

```
 re.match('(")?http(s)?://(.*?)/', ts).group(0)
```

Comment: OK, that's the root cause. :)

Comment: Glad you solved it ;) Although using existing tools like the peeps are suggesting below is defiantly something you should look at. Don't write stuff yourself if it already exists ;) </lazy>

Comment: Why are you encouraging it then if you're recommending "don't write stuff yourself if it already exists"?

Comment: Because it is a solution to the problem. 
The other answer are alternatives (not solutions) for the problem Shawn is having.

Comment: while it is **a** solution, @ShawnZhang should be using urlparse, which is intended for **precisely** this purpose, instead of going through some convoluted regexp developed by a random internet user.

Comment: Hi, both . First of all thanks to your kindness and critical think on how to apply python in best practice. In the url parse case, urlparse is great , but I'm try to export to a executable file which require less size and re is used in elsewhere of code, so in this case , re is better solution . Thanks to you all @hd12

Answer (score 5):

Use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> u = 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#s=Instances,EC2 Management Console,12/3/2012 4:34:57 PM,11,0,,25806'
>>> p = urlparse(u)
>>> p
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='console.aws.amazon.com', path='/ec2/home', params='', query='region=us-east-1', fragment='s=Instances,EC2 Management Console,12/3/2012 4:34:57 PM,11,0,,25806')
>>> p.netloc
'console.aws.amazon.com'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.partition#str.partition) method for this:

```
print(ts.partition('//')[2].partition('/')[0])
>>> console.aws.amazon.com
```

Regular expressions is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: Even your solution is *a bit overkill* as the urlparse module exists for **precisely** this purpose.