# How to use python to replace 'http://xyz.example.com' to 'http://example.com' with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How to use python to replace 'http://xyz.example.com' to 'http://example.com' with regular expression

Note: 'xyz' is just a template. it may be '123' or 'abc-123'

Comment: There is probably a library to strip the subdomain from the URL, if that's what you're looking for

Comment: I would not use `re` for this, rather `urllib.parse`, which is made specifically to parse and create URLs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406300/python-urlparse-extract-domain-name-without-subdomain

Comment: Is regex really a requirement? You dont need them in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This would do it:

```
import re

input = 'http://xyz.example.com'

output = re.sub(r'(?<=http:\/\/).*?\.', '', input)

print(output)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEzk43/1) 
[Python demo](https://repl.it/IRaL/1)

1. `(?<=http:\/\/)` is a positive look behind for `http://`
2. `.*?\.` matches everything that isn't a new line token lazily up until the first `.`