# Python Regex URL from Website / Raw Website without Https & Http

Tags: python

I have python code like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from url parse import urlparse
url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/EgGZmEqY'
parsed = urlparse(url)
site = parsed.netloc
print site
```

I want if the site is RAW or NOT just Grabbing the site without HTTPS and HTTP or WWW. For Example i have website like this from RAW. I want to get the URL just `example.com` without

```
https://example.com
http://example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

How to get without https,http and www ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you just want the TLD (domain name) without the subdomains or scheme.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406300/python-urlparse-extract-domain-name-without-subdomain) Stackoverflow answer, seems all you need is:

```
import tldextract
tldextract.extract('http://forums.news.cnn.com/')
ExtractResult(subdomain='forums.news', domain='cnn', suffix='com')
```

In your case then, i would use this:
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

```
import tldextract

url = 'https://www.pastebin.co.uk/raw/EgGZmEqY'

parsed = tldextract.extract(url)
domain = parsed.domain + '.' + parsed.suffix



print (domain)
```

Comment: You should provide code which works with the OP's exact data.  Cutting and pasting from another question doesn't help much.

Comment: But that just for one domain .. how i want grab it from raw / another website ? like in my pastebin link.