# Getting the TLD and second level domain from a url containing subdomains

Tags: c#, string, url, dns

*There are simple regexes and other easy ways to do this, but they don't handle the edge cases (described below) very well, which is why I'm asking a new question.*

I'm trying to write a fairly simple function to parse DNS responses in C#, but there are some details that are annoying, so I'm asking to see the best way to solve it.

I want to take a url string, like `test.bounce.twitter.com` and remove the `subdomains` to get `twitter.com`.

However, the edge cases are messing me up:

```
bounce.twitter.com    ---> twitter.com
twitter.com           ---> twitter.com
amazon.co.uk          ---> amazon.co.uk (Notice the .co.uk domain!)
news.home.barclays    ---> home.barclays (Note the gTLD with longer than 3 characters; website was formerly barclays.com, belongs to billion dollar bank)
```

Notably, for TLDs like .uk, taking a URL like `news.mail.amazon.co.uk` and returning `co.uk` isn't useful, even though `co.uk` is technically the correct Second Level Domain.

In addition, this list will parse URLs with domains that have gTLDs, like `website.photography` or `website.club` or `website.gallery`, so hard coding a list of TLDs gets messy really quickly.

How can I write a way to strip subdomains from the URL, while still handing the edge cases? Things like handling country codes, gTLDs, etc.

Comment: not sure why people are voting this as offtopic?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/how-to-extract-top-level-domain-name-tld-from-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract top-level domain name (TLD) from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/how-to-extract-top-level-domain-name-tld-from-url)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, it's a good start. It doesn't handle unicode gTLDs well though (it's a country code list for the most part). It's also not in C# but translating it should be easy enough