# How to get domain name for any site?

Tags: python, tld

I am getting output "com" instead of "google.com"

I have tried changing sites name but every site is showing "com"

```
from tld import get_tld

def get_domain_name(url):
    domain_name= get_tld(url)
    return domain_name

print(get_domain_name("https://www.google.com"))
```

I expect output to be "google.com" I have tried this code on Piaza workspace terminal

Comment: Why? TLD is to [Extract the top level domain (TLD) from the URL given](https://pypi.org/project/tld/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract top-level domain name (TLD) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/how-to-extract-top-level-domain-name-tld-from-url)

Comment: "com" is the top-level domain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of those, because I don't think the OP really wants the TLD at all. See @cssko's answer.

Comment: I agree with @brunns. Would it be appropriate to edit the question to reflect what Ritik really wants, the first level domain?

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is the first level domain, so you'd use the function `get_fld`

```py
    from tld import get_fld
    print(get_fld("https://www.google.com")

    >>> google.com
```

See the documentation at [readthedocs](https://tld.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.3/#get-the-first-level-domain-name-as-string-from-the-url-given)